# How can I force the pin angle in a TikZ data visualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels, tikz-datavisualization

Please note that I am *not* using the `pin` option of a node as in [How can I force TikZ pin angle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/how-can-i-force-tikz-pin-angle) and [TikZ node pin angle in 2D plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49632/tikz-node-pin-angle-in-2d-plot), but am instead using the `pin in data` option in a TikZ data visualization.

I have a curve with a pinned label:

[image: Plot of y = f(x), labeled]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=4]
    \datavisualization[
        school book axes,
        visualize as smooth line=myfunction,
        myfunction={pin in data={text=$f(x)$, when=x is 0.5, pin angle=90}}]
    data [set=myfunction, format=function] {
        var x : interval [0:1];
        func y = \value x^2;
    };
\end{document}
```

As might be inferred from my setting `pin angle` to 90, I want the pin to be precisely vertical. I learned from the TikZ manual (§ 61.8.2) that what this tag actually does (along with `pin length`) is introduce an *additional* offset of the label, after the label has already been offset by whatever algorithm `label in data` uses. As a consequence, we are adding the diagonal vector from `label in data` to my vertical (`pin angle=90`) vector, and we do not get a vertical resultant vector.

I want my pin to be vertical. How can I make it behave?

Answer (score 1):

The position of the label is calculated through the `auto` option. It is designed to make labels *floating* alongside the curve without overlapping. As a result the pin-edge is nearly orthogonal to the tangent line for safety.

It is not difficult to override `auto` but it may ruin the whole engine. A workaround is to use the temporary point `(label visualizer coordinate)` to draw your own pin. This point locates at the datapoint which the latest label refers to.

(Nevertheless you still have some options such as rewriting `pin in data`/`label in data`. See `tikzlibrarydatavisualization.code.tex` for their original definition.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=4]{
    \datavisualization[
        school book axes,
        visualize as smooth line=myfunction,
        myfunction={label in data={text=, when=x is 0.5, pin angle=90}}]
    data [set=myfunction, format=function] {
        var x : interval [0:1];
        func y = \value x^2;
    };
    \draw[red](label visualizer coordinate)--+(0,.1)node[above]{$f(x)$};}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. I just have one more question: if I had two functions in the visualization, and each were labeled, would it be possible to adapt your code to modify the positions of both?