# TikZ parallel Edges between Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a simple way to draw the following picture using TikZ. Namely, I would like to only specify the coordinates of the cities and then to connect them by edges using a `\foreach` loop. This would be easy if there were no directed edges at this picture:

[image]

So, more precisely, my question is how to modify the second `\foreach` below to get a picture above.

```
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x/\y/\name/\label/\where in {1.2/1.4/a/{El Paso}/below,     
   1/3.2/b/Albuquerque/above, 2.5/3/c/Amarillo/below, 3.8/4/d/Wichita/above,  
   4.3/3.3/e/Tulsa/45, 5.2/2.8/f/{Little Rock}/right, 4.2/2/g/Dallas/left, 
   4.8/1/h/Houston/right, 3.6/0.6/i/{San Antonio}/below} {
  \draw (\x,\y) circle (.4mm);
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0mm,label=\where:{\footnotesize \label}] (\name) at (\x,\y) {};
}

\foreach \s/\t in {a/b, b/c, c/e, e/d, e/f, f/g, h/g, h/i}
  \path[draw] (\s) edge (\t);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you create a simple "decoration" which simply draws a stroke from the initial to the final point, you can use the `raise` option for decorated paths to get a parallel path. Applying `shorten >` and `shorten <` to this raised path, and putting arrow tips on it, you get the desired result:

[image: Result]

Here is the code (the style `parallel arrow` takes care of all):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sl}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1sp]{
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}{
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    }
}

\tikzset{parallel arrow/.style={->, 
     shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm, 
     decoration={sl,raise=1mm},decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x/\y/\name/\label/\where in {1.2/1.4/a/{El Paso}/below,     
   1/3.2/b/Albuquerque/above, 2.5/3/c/Amarillo/below, 3.8/4/d/Wichita/above,  
   4.3/3.3/e/Tulsa/45, 5.2/2.8/f/{Little Rock}/right, 4.2/2/g/Dallas/left, 
   4.8/1/h/Houston/right, 3.6/0.6/i/{San Antonio}/below} {
  \draw (\x,\y) circle (.4mm);
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0mm,label=\where:{\footnotesize \label}] (\name) at (\x,\y) {};
}

\foreach \s/\t in {a/b, b/c, c/e, e/d, e/f, f/g, h/g, h/i} {
  \path[draw] (\s) edge (\t);
  \path[draw] (\s) edge[parallel arrow] (\t);
  \path[draw] (\t) edge[parallel arrow] (\s);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Update

I added the numbers in each route. I had some fun parametrizing their position so that they can be all put in a single loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sl}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1sp]{
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}{
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    }
}
\tikzset{parallel arrow/.style={latex-,
     shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm, 
     decoration={sl,raise=1mm},decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x/\y/\name/\label/\where in {1.2/1.4/a/{El Paso}/below,     
   1/3.2/b/Albuquerque/above, 2.5/3/c/Amarillo/below, 3.8/4/d/Wichita/above,  
   4.3/3.3/e/Tulsa/45, 5.2/2.8/f/{Little Rock}/right, 4.2/2/g/Dallas/left, 
   4.8/1/h/Houston/right, 3.6/0.6/i/{San Antonio}/below} {
  \draw (\x,\y) circle (.4mm);
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0mm,label=\where:{\footnotesize \label}] (\name) at (\x,\y) {};
}

\tikzset{edge label/.style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1.6mm},
ab/.style={edge label, left},
ba/.style={edge label, right},
bc/.style={edge label, above},
cb/.style={edge label, below},
ce/.style={bc},
ec/.style={cb},
ed/.style={ab},
de/.style={ba},
ef/.style={edge label, below left, inner sep=1mm},
fe/.style={edge label, above right, inner sep=1mm},
fg/.style={edge label, above left, inner sep=1mm},
gf/.style={edge label, below right, inner sep=1mm},
hg/.style={ab},
gh/.style={ba},
hi/.style={bc},
ih/.style={cb}
}  

\foreach \s/\t/\from/\to in {a/b/9/10, b/c/8/11, c/e/7/12, e/d/6/5, 
                             e/f/13/4, f/g/14/3, h/g/15/2, h/i/16/1} {
  \path[draw] (\s) edge (\t) ($(\s)!.5!(\t)$) node[\s\t] {\from} node[\t\s]{\to};
  \path[draw] (\s) edge[parallel arrow] (\t);
  \path[draw] (\t) edge[parallel arrow] (\s);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, @JLDiaz! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I should learn these decorations. =)

Answer (score 10):

JLDiaz's answer is excellent, this is just a small addition to it:

I wanted to avoid hard coding the values for the directed edges, so I thought I'd use the `auto` placement option, which places nodes to the side of a path. However, it turns out that this only happens in 45 degree steps: Nodes are either placed using their `south` anchor, or their `north west` anchor, etc., but no intermediate values. For this application, that's not precise enough. However, if you redefine two internal functions, you can get degree-accuracy placement of the nodes:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother
```

To get an even offset of the labels from the centre line, I used an `ellipse` node shape.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc, shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{sl}{initial}{
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1sp]{
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}{
     \pgflineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    }
}
\tikzset{parallel arrow/.style={latex-,
     shorten >=2mm, shorten <=1mm, 
     decoration={sl,raise=1mm},decorate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x/\y/\name/\label/\where in {1.2/1.4/a/{El Paso}/below,     
   1/3.2/b/Albuquerque/above, 2.5/3/c/Amarillo/below, 3.8/4/d/Wichita/above,  
   4.3/3.3/e/Tulsa/30, 5.2/2.8/f/{Little Rock}/right, 4.2/2/g/Dallas/left, 
   4.8/1/h/Houston/right, 3.6/0.6/i/{San Antonio}/below} {
  \draw (\x,\y) circle (.4mm);
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0mm,label=\where:{\footnotesize \label}] (\name) at (\x,\y) {};
}

\tikzset{
    edge label/.style={
        font=\tiny,
        auto=right,
        ellipse,inner sep=1mm,
    }
}  

\foreach \s/\t/\from/\to in {a/b/9/10, b/c/8/11, c/e/7/12, e/d/6/5, 
                             e/f/13/4, f/g/14/3, h/g/15/2, h/i/16/1} {
  \path[draw] (\s) edge (\t);
  \path[draw] (\s) edge[parallel arrow]
    node [edge label] {\from} (\t);
  \path[draw] (\t) edge[parallel arrow]
  node [edge label] {\to}(\s);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jake! It is nice to have an alternative way to draw this.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another method using `to path` and `calc` library.

An edge and its parallel arrows with labels are drawn by a single `to` operation:

```
\draw (from) to[edge with values=XX and YY] (to);
```

(where `XX` and `YY` are *from->to* and *to->from* labels. They are automatically positioned.)
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  % store of parameters
  parallel distance/.store in=\paradist,
  parallel shorten/.store in=\parashorten,
  parallel label distance/.store in=\paralabdist,
  % default values
  parallel distance=1mm, % distance of parallel arrows from link
  parallel shorten=3mm, % to shorten parallel arrows
  parallel label distance=2.5mm, % distance of label from link
  % main style
  edge with values/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    to path={
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        % middle point
        \coordinate (m) at ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)$);
        % from-to arrow
        \draw[-stealth,shorten >=\parashorten,shorten <=\parashorten]
        ($(\tikztostart)!\paradist!-90:(\tikztotarget)$)
        --
        ($(\tikztotarget)!\paradist!90:(\tikztostart)$)
        % middle of from-to arrow
        coordinate[pos=.5](m from);
        % label of from-to arrow
        \node[font=\tiny] at ($(m)!\paralabdist!(m from)$){#1};
        % to-from arrow
        \draw[-stealth,shorten >=\parashorten,shorten <=\parashorten]
        ($(\tikztotarget)!\paradist!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        --
        ($(\tikztostart)!\paradist!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
        % middle of to-from arrow
        coordinate[pos=.5](m to);
        % label of to-from arrow
        \node[font=\tiny] at ($(m)!\paralabdist!(m to)$){#2};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
      % link
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \foreach \x/\y/\name/\label/\where in {%
      1.2/1.4/a/{El Paso}/below,%     
      1/3.2/b/Albuquerque/above,%
      2.5/3/c/Amarillo/below,%
      3.8/4/d/Wichita/above,%
      4.3/3.3/e/Tulsa/45,%
      5.2/2.8/f/{Little Rock}/right,%
      4.2/2/g/Dallas/left,%
      4.8/1/h/Houston/right,%
      3.6/0.6/i/{San Antonio}/below%
    } {
      \draw (\x,\y) circle (.4mm);
      \node[draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0mm,
      label=\where:{\footnotesize \label}]
      (\name) at (\x,\y) {};
    }

    \foreach \s/\t/\from/\to in {
      a/b/10/9,
      b/c/11/8,
      c/e/12/7,
      e/d/5/6, 
      e/f/13/4,
      f/g/14/3,
      h/g/2/15,
      h/i/16/1
    } {
      \path[draw] (\s) to[edge with values=\from{} and \to] (\t);
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, very elegant!

Comment: I was using this code for some years now. Thanks. Today I noticed that the decoration starts within the nodes. In all examples above this is masked by the shorten, but his won't work if the nodes on both sides of the line aren't equally sized (and also round). You can check by replacing your picture above with only `\node[draw] (a) {large} +(5,0) node[draw] {large} edge[edge with values= x and y] (a);`. Any chance you can fix this?

Comment: @ziggystar My answer works with little circular nodes with no content (as required in the question). You can ask a new question...

Comment: Here's a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359594/parallel-arrows-between-nodes-of-varying-size