# Edge nodes, auto and node distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0)--(1,1) node[auto,midway] {$A$}
 -- (2,0) node[auto,midway] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using `auto` here to get automatic left/right positioning. However, I am not satisfied with the distance between the edge labels and the edge itself, which is a bit too large (my real example is a picture with much more nodes in it, so there is room for confusion if they are not very close).

Is there a way to alter this distance? I tried adding `node distance=something` almost everywhere, but it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no gap between the nodes and the lines (`node distance` applies to a different positioning mechanism). You can see this if you activate `draw` for the nodes

There are two things you can do to move the text closer to the line: Either you decrease the `inner sep`, for example using `inner sep=1pt`, or you set the `outer sep` to a negative value, for example using `outer sep=-3pt`:

[image]

Comment: As a minor tweak, you can consider adding the `circle` option to the nodes as well, so that the spacing won't depend on the direction of the edge.

Comment: @T.Verron: That's what I thought until very recently as well, but it turns out that the `auto` placement only uses the `north`, `north west`, `west`, etc. anchors to place the nodes. Try putting a circle node on a line from `(0,0)` to `(1,3)`: The circle will intersect the line. I posted a code snippet at [TikZ parallel Edges between Nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85669/2552) that makes TikZ use degree-accuracy for placing the nodes. Also, `ellipse` nodes are better for ensuring consistent distance in case your text isn't square.

Comment: @Jake : Interesting, I didn't know that (and it happened to be invisible on this question's MWE). However, I find that if you have to use only one shape and inner sep for all directions, a circle still gives a better output than a rectangle (most notably on vertical edges). Personal taste of course.

Comment: @T.Verron: I was thinking of the case of a horizontal edge with a long label, say, `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- node [auto] {A long label} (4,0);`. If you use a `circle` there, the label will be moved really far from the edge, while using `ellipse` would keep it close to the edge.

Comment: @Jake : Hm, and in that case, the default rectangle would even be better. Good point.

Comment: I struggled with this problem very often. Thanks for this illuminating answer.