# TikZ: slightly move edge label

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, edge

In the MWE below, I would like to bump the label "10" up a bit so it doesn't overlap the line from B to D. There are several questions on stackexchange about edge label positioning but most are about moving it along the edge (using `pos`). [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86386/edge-nodes-auto-and-node-distance) proposes a solution using `inner sep` and `outer sep`, and/or changing the shape of the label's node, but that would also change the horizontal position. I don't want to do that, since I want the label to align with the label "3" on the edge above.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{stage/.style={draw,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=7mm}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

            \node [stage] (A) {A};
            \node [stage] (B) at ($ (A) +(3cm,0cm) $) {B};
            \node [stage] (C) at ($ (B) +(0cm,2cm) $) {C};
            \node [stage] (D) at ($ (B) +(3cm,1cm) $) {D};

            \path[->] (A.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west]  {\small 2}  (B.west);
            \path[->] (C.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west]  {\small 3}  (D.170);
            \path[->] (B.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west]  {\small 10} (D.190);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: shifted 10]

I just added `yshift=5pt` to the node.

```
  \path[->] (B.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west, yshift=5pt]  {\small 10} (D.190);
```

If you want to move it down instead, just make it a negative dimension.

```
  \path[->] (B.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west, yshift=-5pt]  {\small 10} (D.190);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{stage/.style={draw,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=7mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [stage] (A) {A};
  \node [stage] (B) at ($ (A) +(3cm,0cm) $) {B};
  \node [stage] (C) at ($ (B) +(0cm,2cm) $) {C};
  \node [stage] (D) at ($ (B) +(3cm,1cm) $) {D};

  \path[->] (A.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west]  {\small 2}  (B.west);
  \path[->] (C.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west]  {\small 3}  (D.170);
  \path[->] (B.east) edge node[above,at start,anchor=south west, yshift=5pt]  {\small 10} (D.190);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. But given the length of the manual, finding it if you don't know it is like finding a needle in a haystack. Probably worse.

Answer (score 3):

Basic problem is already solved with cfr answer, so I like to point on some possibility to write your code on slightly different way:

- since you load TikZ library positioning, use them in positioning of nodes
- define style for edge nodes (they have the same options), where also defines node's font size
- use option `auto` for edge nodes positioning
- draw lines as segments of path

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}

\tikzset{stage/.style = {draw,minimum width=15mm,minimum height=7mm},
      edgenode/.style = {font=\small,near start}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 12mm,
    auto,
                        ]
\node (A) [stage] {A};
\node (B) [stage,right=of A] {B};
\node (D) [stage,above right=of B]  {D};
\node (C) [stage,above left=of D]   {C};
%
\path[->]   (A) edge node[edgenode]  {2}  (B)
            (C.east) edge node[edgenode]  {3}  (D.170)
            (B.east) edge node[edgenode,xshift=2mm]  {10} (D.190);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The obtained image is almost the same as at cfr answer:

[image]

In the case, that edge nodes can be placed at the middle of the lines (in style for  `edgenode` erase `near start`), than the correction of positioning of "10" is not needed anymore.