# Labeling non axis parallel braces in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces, pgf-decorations

Given two points, the following code draws a brace connecting them and labels it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (4,0);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=1pt,mirror},yshift=0pt] (a) -- (b) node [midway,yshift=-15pt]{$x$};
  \fill (a) circle (2pt);
  \fill (b) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields:
[image]

However, if the line connecting `a` and `b` is not axis-parallel, we can have something like the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (4,2);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=1pt,mirror},yshift=0pt] (a) -- (b) node [midway,yshift=-15pt]{$x$};
  \fill (a) circle (2pt);
  \fill (b) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields: [image]

How can the `x` label be automatically located in this case in the *"right"* place? If there's no automatic way, I guess one has to use a combination of `xshift` and `yshift` and take into account the `raise` and `amplitude` of the brace. When I tried to tweak these I failed... What's the smart way out here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this, the `auto` placement option is a good approach: It takes the slope of the line into account when placing the node, making sure it doesn't overlap the straight line connecting the start and end points. If it's on the wrong side of the line, you can add the `swap` option. In the case of the `brace` decoration, you'll also want to move the node away from the line by setting a larger value for the `outer sep`:

```
\draw [
        decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=1pt,mirror}
    ] (a) -- (b) node [
        midway, auto, swap, outer sep=10pt
    ]{$x$};
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the placement isn't ideal yet. That's because the `auto` placement option only positions the node in 45° steps: east, south east, south, etc. We can "hack" a little internal macro to make the placement work at 1° steps, though. The anchor that is used for a node placed using the `auto` option is determined by a macro called `\tikz@auto@anchor` (`\tikz@auto@anchor` when the `swap` option is used), and at the time when the script is called, the `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` hold the x and y coordinates of a vector pointing in the direction of the line. Putting the following (taken from one of my [earlier answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85669/2552)) into the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@y,\pgf@x)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@y,\pgf@x)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother
```

we get

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@y,\pgf@x)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@y,\pgf@x)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (4,2);
  \draw [
        decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=1pt,mirror}
    ] (a) -- (b) node [
        midway, auto, swap, outer sep=10pt
    ]{$x$};
  \fill (a) circle (2pt);
  \fill (b) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Can you add a short explanation what's the difference between the `@anchor` and the `@anchor@prime`? When which is used?

Comment: @Dror: Glad it helps! `@anchor@prime` is used when the `swap` option is active.