# Polygon drawn with an offset

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I'm looking for a more automated way to draw an area *around* a number of PStricks nodes. The area should be offset by a specific amount so that it will completely contain the vertices inside of it.

Here is a minimal example of a polygon that just traces the vertices/nodes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)%
  \SpecialCoor
  % Identify some vertices
  \pnode(1;0){c}
  \pnode(1;300){g}
  \rput{0}([nodesep=1]c){
    \pnode(1;60){d}
    \pnode(1;0){e}
    \pnode(1;-60){f}
  }

  % Mark area
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!15,linecolor=black!35,dimen=outer]
    (c)(d)(e)(f)(g)

  % Mark vertices
  \qdisk(c){3pt}
  \qdisk(d){3pt}
  \qdisk(e){3pt}
  \qdisk(f){3pt}
  \qdisk(g){3pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The `dimen=outer` has no effect (and is used with `\psframe`), but it gives the idea that I'm after, just in a more general setting. From the [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) showing the effect of the `dimen` key-value (section **13 Line styles** p 25):

[image]

My ideal solution would be something like `offsetsep=5pt`, akin to the `offset` key-value for regular lines (section **31 Node connections**, p 68):

[image]

For example `offsetsep=15pt` will draw a polygon that is offset (outward) by `15pt`, while `offsetsep=-20pt` will draw a polygon that is offset (inward) by `20pt`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this? This part uses a semi-automatic method to calculate the centroid.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pnodes{A}(-2,3)(3,4)(2,-1)(-2,-4)(-4,0)
%
\def\points{(0,0)}
\def\Points{A0}% a dirty trick here
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}{%
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](A\x){3pt}%
    \xdef\points{\points +0.2(A\x)}%
    \xdef\Points{\Points,A\x}%
}
\expandafter\nodexn\expandafter{\points}{O}
\pstHomO
[
    HomCoef=1.1,
    PointSymbol=none,
    CurveType=polygon,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=cyan,
    opacity=0.25,
]{O}{\Points}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Summary on `dimen`

I believe that you feel uncomfortable to remember the following notes as they are illogically defined so they waste your memory (in your brain).

For closed curves:

1. `psframe`, `pscircle`, `psellipse`, `pswedge`, `psellipticwedge` have `dimen=outer` by default.
2. the radial sides of `pswedge` and `psellipticwedge` always have `dimen=middle`, they cannot be changed.
3. `pspolygon`, `psccurve`, and `\pscustom` always have `dimen=middle`, it cannot be changed.

For open curves:

1. `psline`, `pscurve`, `psbezier`, `psarc` always have `dimen=middle`, they cannot be changed.
2. `psellipticarc` has `dimen=outer` by default.

### Animation

This part still uses the old method where the centroid is manually calculated.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointName=none,dotscale=2}
\begin{document}
\multido{\r=.6+.1}{8}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pnode(-.6,.4){O}
\pstGeonode
    (-2,3){A}
    (3,4){B}
    (2,-1){C}
    (-2,-4){D}
    (-4,0){E}
%
\pstHomO
[
    HomCoef=\r,
    PointSymbol=none,
    CurveType=polygon,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=cyan,
    opacity=0.25,
    linearc=.2,
]{O}{A,B,C,D,E}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No animation? :) Just kidding, +1

Comment: @cmhughes: Thanks for upvoting. Animation has been added.

Comment: Only for convex closed curves.

Comment: Does this require you to *know* the (x,y) centre of the object (I haven't experimented)? That is, can I draw some points willy-nilly for a polygon and expect it to scale proportionately without problem? The [`pst-eucl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-eucl/pst-eucl-doc.pdf) just references it as the centre. Did you figure (-.6,.4) out manually?

Comment: @Werner: For convex polygons, the their centroids can be used as the center of homotheti transformation. I calculated the centroid manually with simple formula (sigma x over number of points, sigma y over number of points).

Comment: @Werner For these five points you can use `\nodexn{0.2(A)+0.2(B)+0.2(C)+0.2(D)+0.2(E)}{O}`, don't know how this could be extended automatically to a range of points.

Answer (score 13):

## Drawing parallel paths with the `nfold` library

For TikZ, nowadays the [`nfold` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-nfold) by [Jonathan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681196) can be used. It automatically deals with curves as well. The math isn't trivial for Bézier curves (see the appendix of the package's manual) but it works very well.

I'm using the same paths as in the old answer below but added two diagrams with a new curved path to it where you can see the shortcomings of this mathematical challange. The parallel curves aren't perfectly parallel but you notice this only with `offset=±\pgflinewidth`. Interestingly, for just two lines with `offset=±.5\pgflinewidth` it looks perfect.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz[nodes={circle, fill, inner sep=+1.5pt}]
  \draw[preaction={rounded corners, offset=10pt, fill=gray}]
    (-2, 3) node (A) {}
    ( 3, 4) node (B) {}
    ( 2,-1) node (C) {}
    (-2,-4) node (D) {}
    (-4, 0) node (E) {}
    plot[sharp cycle, samples at={A, ..., E}] (\x);

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.25cm, opacity=.75]
\draw[help lines] (-.5, -.5) grid (7.5, 3.9);
\draw                                           (0,2) rectangle (2,3);
\draw[offset=.5\pgflinewidth]  (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\draw[offset=-.5\pgflinewidth] (3,0) rectangle (4,3);
\path[xshift=5cm, offset=.5\pgflinewidth, draw, line join=round]
  (0,0) -| (1,3) -- (2,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[line width=.2cm]
  \draw[
    postaction={draw=blue,                     offset=+ \pgflinewidth},
    postaction={draw=red, fill=green!50!black, offset=+-\pgflinewidth},
    bend left] (0,0) to ++(30:2) to ++ (-60:2) to ++(-150:2) to cycle;

\tikz[line width=.2cm]
  \path[
    postaction={draw=blue,                     offset=+ .5\pgflinewidth},
    postaction={draw=red, fill=green!50!black, offset=+-.5\pgflinewidth},
    bend left] (0,0) to ++(30:2) to ++ (-60:2) to ++(-150:2) to cycle;
\end{document}
```

### Output (only curves)

[image]
[image]

## Drawing parallel paths with a (decoration)

Just for fun (*cough*) with TikZ (and PGF decorations).

The biggest part of the decoration code has already been provided by [Mark Wilbrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow) in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103088/16595) to [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102975/16595). His decoration `contour lineto` works very fine but doesn’t deal with closed paths.

To work around this issue, the angle of the first segment (here `(A) -- (B)` is saved in `\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle` and later used if the input segment is a `closepath`/`-- cycle`.

If the contour line is drawn on the outer (longer) side of the polygon his code for the `start` state

```
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
```

would have been fine
but this point would lie on the outer side of a contour polygon that lies inside the original path. I don’t know a way to access the last segment’s angle to correct this in the very first state for the first segment. As a work-around the actual first segment of the contour line starts halfway between the first points (here, halfway between `(A)` and `(B)`).

This is sub-optimal. It is advised that the `-- cycle` operator actually travels a certain distance (so that an angle can be calculated). A path like

```
\path (0,0) -| (1,1) -| (0,0) -- cycle;
```

cannot be decorated successfully.

If the option `rounded corners` shall be used on the decorated contour line, the `contour` option (and `rounded corners`) has to be included in a pre- or postaction.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,backgrounds}
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}
\pgfset{
  decoration/contour distance/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{#1}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto closed}{start}{%
  \state{start}[
    next state=draw,
    width=0pt,
    persistent precomputation=\let\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle\pgfdecoratedangle]{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
      {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
      {\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}}%
  }%
  \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment{%
        -\pgfdecoratedangle+\pgf@decorate@firstsegmentangle}%
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten{%
      -\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\pgf@decoration@contour@shorten}
      {\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    \ifpgf@decorate@is@closepath@%
      \pgfpathclose
    \fi
  }%
  \state{final}{}%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  contour/.style={
    decoration={
      name=contour lineto closed,
      contour distance=#1
    },
    decorate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
    (-2, 3) coordinate (A)
    ( 3, 4) coordinate (B)
    ( 2,-1) coordinate (C)
    (-2,-4) coordinate (D)
    (-4, 0) coordinate (E);

\draw[preaction={contour=10pt, rounded corners, fill=gray}]
  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;

\foreach \coord in {A,...,E} \fill (\coord) circle [radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded, line width=.25cm, opacity=.75]
\draw                                           (0,2) rectangle (2,3);
\draw[contour=.5\pgflinewidth]  (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\draw[contour=-.5\pgflinewidth] (3,0) rectangle (4,3);
\path[xshift=5cm,contour=.5\pgflinewidth,draw,line join=round]
  (0,0) -| (1,3) -- (2,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks nice. Could you not also save the angle of the preceding segment? Then you could test if the current segment is a `closepath` and if it is and has length zero, use the previous angle?

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful solution! Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Bezier curves. Do you also have a solution for that?

Comment: @ValenStein Nowadays, we can let `nfold` do the work. See my updated answer.