# alignment of heavy cline with usual width clines

Tags: tables, cline

I am trying to make a table with certain cells emphasized with a thickened border around those cells. My attempt with `\arrayrulewidth` was quite successful, except that the `\cline` thickened this way doesn't always align well with the standard ones, as could be seen from this example:
[image]
as could be seen, the thickened border stick out of the bottom.

Is there any suggestion to improve this?

The code producing the example is

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow,makecell}
\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\Cline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\cline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}

%%% Japanese support
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\cjkfontscale{1.0}
\setmainfont{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKsansfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}
\setCJKmonofont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}
\newCJKfontfamily\boldmincho{Hiragino Mincho ProN W6}

\begin{document}

\def\heavyrulewidth{2pt}
\def\strongvline{\vline width \heavyrulewidth}
\def\arraystretch{2.0}
\def\padcaption#1{\hspace{1.6em}#1\hspace{1.6em}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|c|r|}
  \cline{1-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\raisebox{-8pt}{\padcaption{件名}}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\parbox[t][3em]{12em}{Subject}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}[-10.8pt]{\hspace{1em}{納品先}\hspace{1em}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t][4em]{14em}{Address}} \\
  \Cline{\heavyrulewidth}{1-2}
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\strongvline}c|}{\hspace{-1.5em}\padcaption{納品日}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{|r!{\strongvline}}{\boldmincho\Large 2020/1/1}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
  \Cline{\heavyrulewidth}{1-2}\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\def\arraystretch{1.0}
\vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

(using XeLaTeX. Japanese handling part is non-essential to this question but included to better demonstrate the original usage.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.19 of 2021-07-23), it's easy to draw the required frame *inside the rectangle* with one line of code.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow,makecell}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


%%% Japanese support
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\cjkfontscale{1.0}
\setmainfont{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKsansfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}
\setCJKmonofont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}


\begin{document}

\def\heavyrulewidth{2pt}
\def\strongvline{\vline width \heavyrulewidth}
\def\arraystretch{2.0}
\def\padcaption#1{\hspace{1.6em}#1\hspace{1.6em}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|r|c|r|}% [hvlines]
\hline
  \raisebox{-8pt}{\padcaption{件名}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox[t][3em]{12em}{Subject}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}[-10.8pt]{\hspace{1em}{納品先}\hspace{1em}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t][4em]{14em}{Address}} \\
  \Block[tikz=clip,tikz={draw,line width=4pt},hvlines]{1-2}{}
  \hspace{-1.5em}\padcaption{納品日}
  & \Large 2020/1/1 \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\def\arraystretch{1.0}
\vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

The line is : `\Block[tikz=clip,tikz={draw,line width=4pt},hvlines]{1-2}{}`

- The block has one row and two columns (`1-2`).
- With `tikz=clip`, the rectangle corresponding to the block is used to clip further constructions.
- With `tikz={draw,line width=4pt}`, a frame is drawn with a thikness equal to 4 pt. However, with the clipping, only the interior part of that frame will appear (with a thickness equal to 2 pt).
- The key `hvlines` is used to draw all the rules inside the block (in fact, only one: the central vertical one).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is constructed upon `{tabular}` but adds PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, row and columns. It's easy to use these nodes to draw with Tikz whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow,makecell}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


%%% Japanese support
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\cjkfontscale{1.0}
\setmainfont{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Mincho Pr6N}
\setCJKsansfont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}
\setCJKmonofont[Scale=\cjkfontscale]{Kozuka Gothic Pr6N}
% \newCJKfontfamily\boldmincho{Hiragino Mincho ProN W6}

\begin{document}

\def\heavyrulewidth{2pt}
\def\strongvline{\vline width \heavyrulewidth}
\def\arraystretch{2.0}
\def\padcaption#1{\hspace{1.6em}#1\hspace{1.6em}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|r|c|r|}
\hline
  \raisebox{-8pt}{\padcaption{件名}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox[t][3em]{12em}{Subject}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}[-10.8pt]{\hspace{1em}{納品先}\hspace{1em}}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t][4em]{14em}{Address}} \\
  \hspace{-1.5em}\padcaption{納品日}
  & \Large 2020/1/1 \\
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3-|1) -- (3-|5) ;
\draw [very thick] (2-|1) rectangle (3-|3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\def\arraystretch{1.0}
\vspace{1em}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Great, thanks!! I’ll try it with this method to see whether it could achieve the result I like. 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245141/pgf-tikz-draw-the-border-of-a-shape-inside-it