# Frame size with tcolorbox: is boxrule the same as frame width?

Tags: tcolorbox, frame

I tried two alternative ways to define the width of the frame of my boxes with `tcolorbox`. I defined a `mybox` using the command `frame code` and I compared it with the result of the command `boxrule=4pt`:

```
\documentclass[][1]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{empty,frame code={\draw[line width=4pt, gray!50] (frame.south east) rectangle (frame.north west);}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=4pt,sharp corners,colframe=gray!50,colback=white]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

I expected to obtain the same result. However, the box defined with `frame code` is slightly larger, and it exceeds `\textwidth`.

[image]

Is there a way to define the frame so that the size of the box is identical in the two cases?

Comment: MWE, please ... ?

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=4pt,colframe=gray!50]
text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, frame code={\draw[line width=4pt, gray!50] (frame.south east) rectangle (frame.north west);},width=\linewidth-4pt,center]
text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
` result in a pdf that is closer to the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

When a `\draw` command is used, the central point of the line is placed over the coordinates that you provide.

Therefore, the option `frame code={\draw[line width=4pt, gray!50] (frame.south east) rectangle (frame.north west);}` draws a 4pt width line with 2pt to the left of `frame.south east` and 2pt to the right. And as `frame.south east` and `frame.nort west` are on the border of `\textwidth`, your box is 4pt wider than expected.

An option to change this behaviour is to move the corners of frame code rectangle according to the width of border line. Something like  `frame code={\draw[red, line width=2mm]([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.south east);}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=2mm]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=2mm, 
frame code={\draw[red, line width=2mm]([shift={(.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)}]frame.south east);}]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=2mm, 
frame code={\draw[red, line width=2mm, opacity=.5](frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);}]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding `width=\linewidth-4pt,center` to the definition of your `mybox` results in the following output, with both boxes being equally wide and exactly as wide as the textwidth (Red lines indicate textblock/margins):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{empty,frame code={\draw[line width=4pt, gray!50] (frame.south east) rectangle (frame.north west);}, width=\linewidth-4pt,center}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=4pt,sharp corners,colframe=gray!50,colback=white]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not fully satisfactory, as in some cases the size of the box is not based on `\linewidth` or `\textwidth` (in fact, I need to set it larger). Moreover, the resizing and centering does not seem to work in more complicated setting, e.g. when width and position are different on odd/even page. I wondered if there is a solution that does not force me to set the width by hand.

Comment: Please prepare a MWE that also reflects on that (odd/even pages as well as a specific width are currently not part of your MWE). If you make your box wider than the textwidth, how do you do that? Don't you also use the `width=...` option in your tcolorbox definition, which basically still is "setting the width by hand"?  Also, what's generelly wrong with the first approach using `boxrule` directly?

Comment: The minimal example would not be minimal. I am working in a complicated setting where some boxes need to be larger than textwidth and take over the margin, differently on evenn/odd pages. Moreover, I need to set the frame with `frame code` (instead of `boxrule`) because I have to customize it in some parts. Really, I don't think I should put all this complications in my question, which is simpler: is there a *direct* way to shrink the frame to let it stay within the page without resetting the margins? I find a little strange that boxrule and frame code follow different rules

Comment: @Massimo: Although not directly about `tcolorbox`frames, the following question and its answer are definitely related to the underlying issue might be interesting for you: [PGF/TikZ Draw the border of a shape inside it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245141/134144)

Comment: Thanks, that seems really relevant