# tcolorbox and tikz alignment (inner frame)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, alignment, frame

Using both tikzpicture and tcolorbox, the alignment on the left side is not the same. If you look closely, tcolorbox begins a little bit more left, then tikz does. Any suggestions how to align them? I dont want to change tikz. I want that tcolorbox starts where tikz does.

Probably this happens because of tcolorbox makes an "outer frame" instead of an "inner frame". But I dont know how to fix it.

[image]

**Tikz:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[color=black!30!,line width=0.3mm] (0,0.6)--(17.6,0.6);
\fill [fill=black!30!] (0,0)--(1.7,0)--(1.7,0.6)--(0,0.6)-- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\vspace*{-6mm}
\hspace*{2mm}\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Lösung #1}}
```

**Tcolorbox:**

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
width=100mm,boxrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,box align=top,enhanced,interior hidden,left=2mm,right=2mm,top=0mm,bottom=2mm,% 
frame code={
\draw[line width=0.3mm,color=black!30!] (frame.north west) --   (frame.north east) --  (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)  -- cycle;
}
]
Text in tcolorbox
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587756/1952

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is,

- in `tikz`, the bounding box is enlarged at the endpoints of drawn lines by half the line width, while
- in `tcolorbox`, `frame code` has *no effect* on the bounding box (of the resulting `tcolorbox`).

Most likely `grow sidewards by=<length>`, where `<length> = - <half the frame line width>` is what OP needs. It shrinks the text width, enlarges the bounding box (horizontally), and as a result keeps the total width unchanged.

Compared to [@polyn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609381), the space between all text parts and frame is unchanged.

To make the bounding box take the height added by `frame code` into consideration, one can additionally use `enlarge top by` and `enlarge bottom by`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}

\newlength{\myframewidth}
\setlength{\myframewidth}{5pt} % by default, tikz line width is 0.4pt

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  width=100mm,
  enhanced,interior hidden,
  grow sidewards by=-.5\myframewidth,
  frame code={
    \draw[line width=\myframewidth,color=black!30!]
      (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
  },
  show bounding box, % just for debugging
]
  enlarge only horizontally
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  width=100mm,
  enhanced,interior hidden,
  grow sidewards by=-.5\myframewidth,
  enlarge top by=.5\myframewidth,
  enlarge bottom by=.5\myframewidth,
  frame code={
    \draw[line width=\myframewidth,color=black!30!]
      (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
  },
  show bounding box, % just for debugging
]
  enlarge both horizontally and vertically
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=100mm]
  simple tcolorbox with \texttt{width=100mm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\leavevmode
\smash{\llap{\rule{.2pt}{5cm}}}%
\rule{100mm}{.5pt}%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{.2pt}{5cm}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image below will help you (0.15mm is half the thickness of the line)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [fill=black!30] (0,0)--(1.7,0)--(1.7,0.6)--(0,0.6)-- cycle;
    \draw[color=red,line width=0.3mm] (0,0.6)--(17.6,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-6mm}
\hspace*{2mm}\textcolor{white}{Text}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}% align in left margin
    \fill [fill=black!30] (-0.15mm,0)--(1.7,0)--(1.7,0.6)--(-0.15mm,0.6)-- cycle;
    \draw[color=red,line width=0.3mm,line cap=rect] (0,0.6)--(17.6,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{-6mm}
\hspace*{2mm}\textcolor{white}{Text}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    width=100mm,boxrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,box align=top,enhanced,interior hidden,left=2mm,right=2mm,top=0mm,bottom=2mm,% 
    frame code={
        \draw[line width=0.3mm,color=black!30!] (frame.north west) --   (frame.north east) --  (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)  -- cycle;
    }
    ]
    Text in tcolorbox
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[% align in left margin
    width=100mm,boxrule=0mm,boxsep=0mm,box align=top,enhanced,interior hidden,left=2mm,right=2mm,top=0mm,bottom=2mm,% 
    frame code={
        \draw[line width=0.3mm,color=black!30!] ([xshift=0.15mm]frame.north west) --   (frame.north east) --  (frame.south east) -- ([xshift=0.15mm]frame.south west)  -- cycle;
    }
    ]
    Text in tcolorbox
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]