# Diagonally cut three line in TikZ following the inclination of a character

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made this symbol and would like the right-hand side of the symbol to be cut diagonally following the inclination of the character 'A'. How can I solve this?
This should be the final effect:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle;
\draw[green!80!black, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (11,0) -- cycle (-1,-3) rectangle (11,7);
\draw[red, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\draw[white, line width=15pt, rounded corners] (11,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\node[scale=2.7] at (11.9,-0.1) {{\Huge \textbf{\textit{A}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You just have to change a bit your `clip`s to make the right line diagonal.

Comment: Hi Seb, thank you for your comments. I can't figure it out :-(

Comment: You should always cite [code written by others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634781/125871). I believe it was @hpekristiansen who had the main idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-1,7) -- (13,7) -- (12.3,0.9) -- (10.2,-2.5) -- (-1,-2.5) -- cycle;
\fill[white, rounded corners] (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (12.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[green!80!black, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip[rounded corners] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:1) -| (12.5,0) -- cycle (-1,-3) rectangle (12.5,7);
\draw[red, line width=50pt, rounded corners] (15,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2);
\end{scope}
\draw[white, line width=15pt, rounded corners] (12.5,0) -- (0,0) -- (1,5) -- (3,6) -- (5,5) -- (6.4,-2) -- ([turn]0:.01);
\end{scope}
\node[scale=5.4, white] at (12.4,0.7) {{\Huge \textbf{\textit{A}}}};
\node[scale=2.7] at (11.9,-0.1) {{\Huge \textbf{\textit{A}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red white and green striped logo]

Comment: What does the ([turn]0:1) notation mean?  Or can you give me a pointer to where it is discussed in the manual?

Comment: It means continue at an angle of `0` degrees(same direction) a distance of `1` unit

Comment: @hpekristiansen You should explain your approach.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Can you at least comment a little your code?