# Postaction and even odd rule

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to fill the space between two inward offsets of a polygone. Thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133670/272334) fantastic answer I could figure out how to create the inward shapes. However, I cannot find a way to fill the area between both paths using the `even odd rule`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymode=log, 
        xmin=0, xmax=200, 
        ymin=1, ymax=10000, 
        grid=both]

    \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
        \fill
    [postaction={offset=-1pt, draw=red}]
    [postaction={offset=-3pt, draw=blue}]
   (axis cs: 52,10000) .. controls (axis cs: 198,207) .. (axis cs: 199,5) -- 
   (axis cs: 159,5) .. controls (axis cs: 159,166) .. (axis cs: 50,5371) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
   
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have three separate paths. The `even odd rule` is used on one path(with self intersections or voids). I do not know the exact meaning of "fill the area between both paths"!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymode=log, 
xmin=0, xmax=200, 
ymin=1, ymax=10000, 
grid=both,
]
\draw[save path=\mypath](52,10000) .. controls (198,207) .. (199,5) -- (159,5) .. controls (159,166) .. (50,5371) -- cycle;
\draw[red, thick, use path=\mypath, offset=-1pt, save path=\mypathA];
\draw[blue, thick, use path=\mypath, offset=-3pt, save path=\mypathB];
\fill[even odd rule, use path=\mypathA \mypathB];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with ring shape and filled area]

Comment: `use path=\mypathA \mypathB` isn't really right (a `path picture` would not be clipped correctly). Better to define `\tikzset{append path/.code=\tikz@addmode{\expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@addtocurrentpath\expandafter{#1}}}` and then use `use path=\mypathA, append path=\mypathB` or `append path/.list={\mypathA, \mypathB}` even.