# pscustom how to close the paths

Tags: pstricks

Why pscustom fails to produce a closed path such as this mwe :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\pscustom{%
\psline(1,0)(0,4)(-1,0)%
\psellipticarc(0,0)(1,.5){180}{360}%
\closepath}
\end{document}
```

I thought that all this would be one stroke. But it does not work. I try to draw a cone here. I tried linecap and join, nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133657/82917, lines have `dimen=middle` but arcs have `dimen=outer` by default. Adding `dimen=middle` (either "globally" to `\pscustom` or "locally" to `\psellipticarc`) seems to help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\pscustom[dimen=middle]{%
   \psline(1,0)(0,4)(-1,0)%
   \psellipticarc(0,0)(1,.5){180}{360}% or \psellipticarc[dimen=middle] here
   \closepath
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I did not know of this option. Looks good enough. Thank you.