# Additional parallel paths and "shorten"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, decorations, pgf-decorations

A while ago, I have stumbled upon a very nice solution for parallel paths drawn with TikZ, which can be found here: [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102975/draw-additional-parallel-paths-in-tikz).

However, when trying to use this for my purposes - namely in combination with the `shorten >=` and `shorten <=` options - I discovered that this solution doesn't quite behave as expected. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/contour distance/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \let\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance=\pgfmathresult}%
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto}{start}
{
    \state{start}[next state=draw, width=0pt]{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    }
    \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{       
        \pgfmathparse{-\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
        \let\shorten=\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\shorten}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%  
    }
    \state{final}{
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    }   
}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw=black, fill=blue!20, inner sep=1em},
    arrow/.style={->,draw=black, shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm},
    quintuple/.style={
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=-4pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=-2pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=+2pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=+4pt},draw=black, decorate},
    },
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (box1) {Box 1};
    \node[box,above right=of box1] (box2) {Box 2};
    \draw[arrow,quintuple] (box1) |- (box2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The picture this produces looks like this:

[image: Screwed up arrows]

The arrow ends are all screwed up, and I can't figure out why this happens. Can anybody provide a solution that has nice arrow ends (or at least explain what's happening here)?

Comment: One note: `\tikzset{}` goes in the preamble. (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @Alenanno No need. That's `\usetikzlibrary{}` that is important. `\tikzset` is just key setter and can set anywhere.

Comment: @percusse Oh, I see, it's not mandatory. I still prefer settings in the preamble. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `final` state that is messing things up, but in your case the `final` state is not needed because you don't need or want the added paths to end at the same point as the base path.

Simply remove the declaration of the `final` state and everything works as we'd like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/contour distance/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \let\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance=\pgfmathresult}%
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto}{start}
{
    \state{start}[next state=draw, width=0pt]{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    }
    \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{       
        \pgfmathparse{-\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
        \let\shorten=\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\shorten}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%  
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={draw=black, fill=blue!20, inner sep=1em},
    arrow/.style={->,draw=black, shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm},
    quintuple/.style={
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=-4pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=-2pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=+2pt},draw=black, decorate},
      postaction={decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=+4pt},draw=black, decorate},
    },
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (box1) {Box 1};
    \node[box,above right=of box1] (box2) {Box 2};
    \draw[arrow,quintuple] (box1) |- (box2);
    \draw[arrow,quintuple] (box1) -| (box2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]