# Tikz and enveloping border

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add an enveloping border around the blue line in this MWE?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, line width=10pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS. I found out that something similar is possible with MetaPost in this previous answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330016,
but I'd like to know if this is also possible with Tikz.

Comment: Why not another line with thickness of `8pt`  inside,  
`\draw[white, line width=8pt,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); `

Comment: tikz offers the option `[double]` which does what @SalimBou proposes, it draws the path twice with two different thicknesses. However, it does not close the path ends. For that, you would have to construct a secondary path, along the lines of `($0+5pt$,0) -- ` (with calc library). If there is a way to automate that, I am unaware of it.

Comment: What's an enveloping border? Around what? The picture? The line?

Comment: @Huang_d You can shorten only the main path, though, which would have the same effect, I think. And do it in `preaction` (or `postaction`) rather than using `double`.

Comment: The suggestion of @salim-bou works fine for my case.

Comment: @cfr Around the line.

Comment: @SalimBou Would you like to write up an answer?

Comment: @SalimBou I think `shorten` should be negative to enlarge the line at endings.

Answer (score 2):

This is Salim Bou solution with negative `shorten` values and declared as a style which adds a `preaction`.

Style `border` has three parameters:lower line width, border width (applied to `shorten`) and color.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[border/.style n args={3}{
    preaction={draw=#3, line width=#1, shorten <=-#2, shorten >=-#2}}]
\draw[blue, line width=10pt, border={14pt}{2pt}{green}](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 

\draw[blue, line width=10pt, border={14pt}{2pt}{green}](3,0)rectangle++(2,3); 

\draw[blue, line width=10pt, border={14pt}{2pt}{green}] (7,1) circle(1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103088/121799). This answer comes with an `Outline` style, which has one argument, the distance from the center to the line to the contour. The width is then twice this length.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103088/121799
\def\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance{0pt}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/contour distance/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \let\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance=\pgfmathresult},%
    /pgf/decoration/contour name/.store in=\ContourName,
    /pgf/decoration/contour name=mycontour
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{contour lineto}{start}
{
    \state{start}[next state=draw, width=0pt]{
    \pgfcoordinate{\ContourName-0}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
    }
    \state{draw}[next state=draw, width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{       
        \pgfmathparse{-\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance*cot(-\pgfdecoratedangletonextinputsegment/2+90)}%
        \let\shorten=\pgfmathresult%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\shorten}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%  
    %\stepcounter{Outline}
    \pgfcoordinate{\ContourName-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength+\shorten}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}
    }
    \state{final}{
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{\pgfdecoratedcontourdistance}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength}{0pt}}
    }   
}
\tikzset{Outline/.style={ postaction={
        decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=-#1,contour name=mycontourA},draw=blue,
         decorate},
        postaction={
        decoration={contour lineto, contour distance=#1,contour name=mycontourB},draw=blue,
         decorate},}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,line width=10pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
\path[blue,very thick,Outline=5pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\path[blue,line width=2pt,Outline=5pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,scale=2]
\path[blue,line width=4pt,Outline=10pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**NOTE**: This works only with polygons which are not closed.