# tikz pic scaling with line width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, scale

How can I scale also the values of line width in this MWE?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    mytest/.pic = {
      \draw[blue, line width=0.5cm](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
      \draw[white, line width=0.4cm,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt](0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0);
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0cm,0cm){mytest};
  \pic [scale=5] at (5cm,0cm){mytest};
  %HELP GRID LINES: 
  \draw[very thin, gray!20,step=1cm] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Related question: [Tikz and enveloping border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380976/tikz-and-enveloping-border)[image: ][1]]

Comment: You are hard-coding the line widths and other distances. What do you expect?

Comment: @marmot Do you have another option? (the distances are scaled correctly)

Comment: I have not really thought about this, but one way that will work is to use line widths which are a multiple of a macro `\mylinewidth`, which you could adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    mytest/.pic = {
        \draw[
        blue,
        scale=#1,
        line width=#1*4pt,
        double distance between line centers=#1*8pt,
        double,
        shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
        (0,0)--(90:1.5)--(60:2.5)--(30:3.0); 
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0cm,0cm){mytest={1}};
  \pic at (5cm,0cm) {mytest=4};
  %HELP GRID LINES: 
  \draw[very thin, gray!20,step=1cm] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```