# TikZ: coloring multiple passes over the same path between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-path

I'm drawing a lattice of nodes and I would like to highlight certain paths with different colors.  When the paths overlap, I would like the colors to appear adjacent to each other.  I've seen solutions on this site for when the nodes appear either only vertically or only horizontally displaced from one another.  My situation, for which I haven't found an answer yet, is one where the nodes are offset by some nonzero slope.

I can *kind of* achieve the effect I want.  But,
I'm not entirely happy with my solution to this.  It requires a bit too much tinkering on my part.

To duplicate what I've done, I'd like something to *transform canvas* orthogonally to some path.  (Or perhaps there's another approach I'm unaware of.)

Here's my attempt at this,

[image]

Here's my code for this:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\aev{\dimexpr12pt+0.65cm}
\def\aeh{\dimexpr12pt+1.00cm}
\newcommand\aes[2]{\scalebox{\ifcase#1\or1.00\or0.90\or0.80\or0.70\fi}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  aec/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0.80cm},
  ae transform top/.style={transform canvas={yshift= 1.3pt,xshift= 0.3pt}},
  ae transform bot/.style={transform canvas={yshift=-1.3pt,xshift=-0.3pt}},
  ]

%% ------------------------------------------------------------
%% a bit of a work around for several issues                   
%% the primary one here is how "transformed" path connect      
%% at the nodes                                                
%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\coordinate (cA) at (0,0);
\coordinate (cB) at ($(cA.south)+(0,-\aev)$);
\coordinate (cC) at ($(cB.south)+(0,-\aev)$);
\coordinate (cD) at ($(cC.south)+(0,-\aev)$);
\coordinate (cAB) at ($($(cA.south)!0.5!(cB.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);
\coordinate (cBC) at ($($(cB.south)!0.5!(cC.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);
\coordinate (cCD) at ($($(cC.south)!0.5!(cD.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);
\coordinate (cABC) at ($($(cAB.south)!0.5!(cBC.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);
\coordinate (cBCD) at ($($(cBC.south)!0.5!(cCD.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);
\coordinate (cABCD) at ($($(cABC.south)!0.5!(cBCD.north)$)+(\aeh,0pt)$);

\node[aec] (A) at (cA) {A};
\node[aec] (B) at (cB) {B};
\node[aec] (C) at (cC) {C};
\node[aec] (D) at (cD) {D};
\node[aec] (AB) at (cAB) {\aes{2}{AB}};
\node[aec] (BC) at (cBC) {\aes{2}{BC}};
\node[aec] (CD) at (cCD) {\aes{2}{CD}};
\node[aec] (BCD) at (cBCD) {\aes{3}{BCD}};

\draw (AB) -- (A);
\draw (AB) -- (B);
\draw (BC) -- (B);
\draw (BC) -- (C);
\draw (CD) -- (C);
\draw (CD) -- (D);
%\draw (ABC) -- (AB);
%\draw (ABC) -- (BC);
\draw (BCD) -- (BC);
\draw (BCD) -- (CD);
%\draw (ABCD) -- (ABC);
%\draw (ABCD) -- (BCD);

%% ------------------------------------------------------------
%% Using my "coordinate" construct work around to make the     
%% lines connecting nodes look more "beautiful                 
%% ------------------------------------------------------------

\draw[  red,line width=3pt]           (cABC) -- (BC);
\draw[green,line width=3pt]           (cABC) -- (AB) -- (B);

\draw[green,line width=3pt,ae transform top] (cABCD) -- (cABC);
\draw[  red,line width=3pt,ae transform bot] (cABCD) -- (cABC);

%% ------------------------------------------------------------
%% Using a more pure "node" approach to this, but the          
%% transformed colored paths don't connect to the nodes very   
%% beautifully and I'm not happy with that.                    
%% ------------------------------------------------------------

\node[aec,fill=white] (ABC) at (cABC) {\aes{3}{ABC}};
\node[aec,fill=white] (ABCD) at (cABCD) {\aes{4}{ABCD}};

\draw[ blue,line width=3pt] (ABCD) -- (BCD) -- (BC);

\draw[ red,line width=3pt,ae transform top] (BC) -- (B);
\draw[blue,line width=3pt,ae transform bot] (BC) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, there are two issues I'd like fixed.

1. The most important of the two is how to more easily *transform canvas* or use some other technique to color the same *essential* path in parallel (with up to three colors potentially used for the same path).
2. Of secondary interest (since I already have a bit of a work-around) is:  once I've got the path colored as I would like (point 1), how can I make the connection with the nodes more *beautiful*.

Regarding the second point, you can see the appearance created by my *work around* between nodes `ABCD` and `ABC`.

You can see the *ugly* connect created by not using my *work-around* between the nodes `BC` and `B`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the methode in this answer: [Draw additional parallel paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102975/draw-additional-parallel-paths-in-tikz)

-or as it is just lines, you can calculate the shift with `calc` notation. Line join to circle nodes will never be nice, when the line width is much larger than the node boundary width. I avoid this by drawing the lines in the background. Instead of understanding your code, I started over and I just copied code instead of making relevant styles.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{aec/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, minimum size=0.80cm, on grid, fill=white}}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5 cm and 1.5cm]
\node[aec] (A) {A};
\node[aec, below right=of A] (AB) {\scalebox{0.9}{AB}};
\node[aec, below left=of AB] (B) {B};
\node[aec, below right=of B] (BC) {\scalebox{0.9}{BC}};
\node[aec, below left=of BC] (C) {C};
\node[aec, below right=of C] (CD) {\scalebox{0.9}{CD}};
\node[aec, below left=of CD] (D) {D};
\node[aec, below right=of AB] (ABC) {\scalebox{0.8}{ABC}};
\node[aec, below right=of BC] (BCD) {\scalebox{0.8}{BCD}};
\node[aec, below right=of ABC] (ABCD) {\scalebox{0.7}{ABCD}};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw (A) -- (AB);
\draw (C) -- (BC);
\draw (C) -- (CD);
\draw (D) -- (CD);
\draw[green, line width=3pt] (B.center) -- (AB.center);
\draw[green, line width=3pt] (AB.center) -- (ABC.center);
\draw[red,   line width=3pt] (BC.center) -- (ABC.center);
\draw[blue,  line width=3pt] (BC.center) -- (BCD.center);
\draw[blue,  line width=3pt] (BCD.center) -- (ABCD.center);
\draw[red,   line width=3pt] ($ (B.center)!1.5pt!90:(BC.center) $) -- ($ (BC.center)!1.5pt!-90:(B.center) $);
\draw[blue,  line width=3pt] ($ (B.center)!-1.5pt!90:(BC.center) $) -- ($ (BC.center)!-1.5pt!-90:(B.center) $);
\draw[green, line width=3pt] ($ (ABC.center)!1.5pt!90:(ABCD.center) $) -- ($ (ABCD.center)!1.5pt!-90:(ABC.center) $);
\draw[red,   line width=3pt] ($ (ABC.center)!-1.5pt!90:(ABCD.center) $) -- ($ (ABCD.center)!-1.5pt!-90:(ABC.center) $);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nodes with colored lines]

To avoid `calc` completely, you could also do a `shift={(\angle:1.5pt)}` where `\angle` can be calculated with `atan2` using the `let` notation. I would do a coordinate shift rather than a canvas shift.

**Edit:**

Node placement without `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\aev{\dimexpr12pt+0.65cm}
\def\aeh{\dimexpr12pt+1.00cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  aec/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0.80cm},
  ]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-\aev] A);
\coordinate (C) at ([yshift=-\aev] B);
\coordinate (D) at ([yshift=-\aev] C);
\coordinate (AB) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)+(\aeh,0)$);
\coordinate (BC) at ($(B)!0.5!(C)+(\aeh,0)$);
\coordinate (CD) at ($(C)!0.5!(D)+(\aeh,0)$);
\coordinate (ABC) at ($(AB)!0.5!(BC)+(\aeh,0)$);
\coordinate (BCD) at ($(BC)!0.5!(CD)+(\aeh,0)$);
\coordinate (ABCD) at ($(ABC)!0.5!(BCD)+(\aeh,0)$);
\foreach \text/\scale in {A/1, B/1, C/1, D/1, AB/2, BC/2, CD/2, ABC/3, BCD/3, ABCD/4}
\node[aec] at (\text) {\scalebox{\ifcase\scale\or1.00\or0.90\or0.80\or0.70\fi}{\text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Node placement without `positioning` and without `calc`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\def\aev{\dimexpr12pt+0.65cm}
\def\aeh{\dimexpr12pt+1.00cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  aec/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0.80cm},
  ]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at ([yshift=-\aev] A);
\coordinate (C) at ([yshift=-\aev] B);
\coordinate (D) at ([yshift=-\aev] C);
\path (A) --coordinate[right=\aeh](AB) (B);
\path (B) --coordinate[right=\aeh](BC) (C);
\path (C) --coordinate[right=\aeh](CD) (D);
\path (AB) --coordinate[right=\aeh](ABC) (BC);
\path (BC) --coordinate[right=\aeh](BCD) (CD);
\path (ABC) --coordinate[right=\aeh](ABCD) (BCD);
\foreach \text/\scale in {A/1, B/1, C/1, D/1, AB/2, BC/2, CD/2, ABC/3, BCD/3, ABCD/4}
\node[aec] at (\text) {\scalebox{\ifcase\scale\or1.00\or0.90\or0.80\or0.70\fi}{\text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If nodes needs to be named, you can use e.g.:

```
\node[aec] (\text_node) at (\text) {\scalebox{\ifcase\scale\or1.00\or0.90\or0.80\or0.70\fi}{\text}};
```

for node names `(A_node), ...`.

Comment: Life without `calc` will be nasty for what I'm actually doing.  I had not thought of using the `!1.5pt!90:` approach since I rarely use it.  Great suggestion.  Also, great suggestion for the use of `pgfonlayer`.  I had considered using `A.center` and if this were all I was doing with these points/nodes that would be fine.  But, for my document with everything else I'm doing in it, using `coordinates` really seems more practical.  Great ideas.  Let me think on this a bit and play with it.

Comment: If you define all coordinates, draw all lines and first then draw all nodes - you will not need layers.

Comment: Definitely.  But, by the way, I didn't mean the comment about `A.center` as a criticism of your answer.  I really like this answer for how you approached it all.

Comment: @A.Ellett: I made some additions - just in case you can use it.

Comment: I wish I could upvote again.  Your edit is beautiful.  It's so clean compared to my code.  Thank you.