# Shift up a bond in ChemFig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

In ChemFig, the "bond join=true" option does not work with "cram" bonds (see A, it is zoomed at join).

It is possible to increase the length of the bond with the "shorten" option, but the joint still has a difference in height (see B)

Is there any option/command in tikz that can be used in the bond options to shift up a bond at a height "H" (see B)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{bond offset =1pt,bond join=true,atom sep =2em,cram width =3pt,cram dash width =0.4pt,cram dash sep =0.4pt}
    \chemfig{<[:300]-[0,,,,line width = 3pt]>[:60]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `line cap=round`? Not a "shift" solution though ...

Comment: It wasn't bad, after adjusting the bond length with "shorten". Thanks

Comment: Another idea: use a [decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103088/47927) =D It seems that the line is not a to-path, so you can't easily shift it by replacement.

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of the round?

Comment: I think you can't change the roundness of `line cap=round`. But maybe go with arrow heads? You could probably use `Triangle[]` from the `arrows.meta` library.

Answer (score 3):

I think, shifting the path is not that simple. It seems that the path drawn by `chemfig` is not a to-path, so replacement is not feasable using the `to path` key for example.

But what about these two ideas:

1. Use `line cap=round`.
2. Use `Triangle Cap` as arrow tip (via `arrows.meta`).

Another, probably somewhat too complicated solution could be to [use a decoration to draw a shifted path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103088/47927).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    sharp caps/.style={
        {Triangle Cap[length=0.8pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=0.8pt]}, 
        shorten >=-1.9pt, 
        shorten <=-1.9pt
    }
}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{
    bond offset=1pt,
    bond join=true,
    atom sep=2em,
    cram width=3pt,
    cram dash width=0.4pt,
    cram dash sep=0.4pt
}
    \chemfig{<[:300]-[0,,,,line width=3pt, line cap=round]>[:60]}
    \chemfig{<[:300]-[0,,,,line width=3pt, sharp caps]>[:60]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

Well, almost ...

Comment: The solution using "caps" works well for angles of 60 degrees, but you need to adjust the parameters to use other angles. This gets complicated for drawing large molecules

Answer (score 3):

With a little geometry we can fill the gap ...(complicated)

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em,cram width=3pt} % 2em=24pt
    \chemfig{<[@{A1,1}:300]-[0,,,,line width=3pt]>[@{A2,0}:60]}
    \chemmove{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tang}{\fpeval{atand(1.5/24)}} % \tang is the half angle of the sides of the cram bond
        \path (A1) ++(-90:1.5pt) coordinate (B1);
        \path (A1) ++(210:1.7pt) coordinate (C1);
        \path (C1) ++(300-\tang:\fpeval{0.65/cosd(300-\tang-270)}pt) coordinate (D1);
        \fill[red] (A1) -- (C1) -- (D1) -- ([xshift=1pt]B1) -- cycle; % xshift eliminates the artefact
        \path (A2) ++(-90:1.5pt) coordinate (B2);
        \path (A2) ++(-30:1.7pt) coordinate (C2);
        \path (C2) ++(-120+\tang:\fpeval{0.65/cosd(300-\tang-270)}pt) coordinate (D2);
        \fill[red] (A2) -- (C2) -- (D2) -- ([xshift=-1pt]B2) -- cycle;
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Filling the gap with a pic...

cramgap={cram width/pt}{length of the cram bond/pt}{bonds angle}

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/cramgap/.style n args={3}{code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tang}{\fpeval{atand((#1/2)/#2)}}
    \path (0,0) coordinate (cgO);
    \path (cgO) ++(-90:\fpeval{(0.4+#1)/2}pt) coordinate (cgA);
    \path (cgO) ++(\fpeval{90+#3}:\fpeval{(0.4+#1)/2}pt) coordinate (cgB);
    \path (cgB) ++(\fpeval{180+#3-\tang}:\fpeval{(0.2+#1/2)*(1-cosd(180-#3))/cosd(-90+#3-\tang)}pt) coordinate (cgX);
    \fill[red] (cgO) -- (cgB) -- (cgX) -- ([xshift=\fpeval{#3>0?1:-1}pt]cgA) -- cycle;
}}}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=24pt,cram width=2.6pt} % 2em=24pt
    \chemfig{<[@{A1,1}:310]-[:0,,,,line width=3pt]>[@{A2,0}:40]} % line width=0.4pt + cram width
    \chemmove{\path (A1) pic{cramgap={2.6}{24}{130}};
        \path (A2) pic{cramgap={2.6}{24}{-140}};}
    
    \chemfig{<[@{A1,1}:330]-[:20,,,,line width=3pt]>[@{A2,0}:60]}
    \chemmove{\path (A1) pic[rotate=20]{cramgap={2.6}{24}{130}};
        \path (A2) pic[rotate=20]{cramgap={2.6}{24}{-140}};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it is possible, but complicated... This whole code could be avoided if it were possible to move the horizontal bond bar a little upwards.  From what I understand, this is not possible because we do not have the starting and ending points of the bond.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a key which would allow to use this as option to the `\chemfig` command?

Comment: @Jasper Habicht It probably is possible but I can't do it.

Comment: I managed to get it working for the first point, but it is difficult for the second, as the coordinate is defined only later.

Answer (score 2):

I created a way to shift up the link, but many may find it a bad solution.

One problem was not knowing the starting and ending points of the bond. Then I marked these points with "@{x}", a ChemFig feature to mark positions in molecules.

I made the bond invisible using [,,,,draw=none]

Then, using \chemmove, I shifted up the start and end points using "\node", and created a straight line to replace the bond using "\draw".

Well, technically this isn't a "chemfig bond" (-[,<length.,,,,,,]), but it uses a lot of what ChemFig already uses to build molecules and is easy to tweak the parameters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{bond offset =0.5pt,bond join=true,atom sep =2em,cram width =3pt,cram dash width =0.2pt,cram dash sep =0.4pt}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{<[:300]@{a}-[0,,,,draw=none]@{b}>[:60]}
\chemmove{
    \node[at=(a),yshift=.57pt](a){};
    \node[at=(b),yshift=.57pt](b){};
    \draw[-,line width=3pt,shorten <=-1.2pt,shorten >=-1.2pt](a)--(b);}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]