# A line parallel to an edge in a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a graph in TikZ built using code like the following

```
\node[...] (1) at (0,0) {1};

\node[...] (2) at (1,1) {2} 
  edge (1);
```

I would like to add a short line (with an arrow) parallel to the edge between 1 and 2, at some distance from the edge (and attach a label to the short line). Is there an easy way of doing it, without calculating coordinates?

Comment: I think [TikZ parallel Edges between Nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85645/13304) might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference for understanding decorations library? I couldn't find any information in TikZ manual. Also what is \tikzset and why for examplenot use \tikzstyle instead?

Comment: Yes, on the pgfmanual you have an introduction in 21 Decorated Paths then the library is explained in detail in 30 Decoration Library. The macro `\tikzset` is the recommended way to define styles while `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a decoration, like in the answers pointed by Claudio Fiandrino, and this can be specially useful if you have several arrows like this in your drawing.

A different approach, which can be useful for single particular cases, could be the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[] (1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[] (2) at (1,1) {2} 
  edge (1);

\draw[->] ($(1)!0.3!(2)!1mm!90:(2)$) -- ($(1)!0.7!(2)!1mm!90:(2)$)
 node[midway,sloped,above] {\tiny label};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

The syntax used for this is called "interpolated coordinates". In the above code you can tweak the amounts `0.3` and `0.7` (which are the fraction of the segment length at which the arrow will start and end) and `1mm` (which is the distance between the parallel arrow and the main segment). You can also replace `90` by `-90` if you want the parallel arrow *below* the original segment (and in this case, of course, you should use `below` option for the label).

Answer (score 0):

A way to build a parallel to (a)--(b) at a distance 1cm:

```
\draw ($(a)!0cm!(b)!-1cm!90:(b)$) -- ($(b)!0cm!(a)!1cm!90:(a)$);
```