# Necklace edge labels in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am generating a tikz necklace graph and I want to label the edges, and for the life of me I can't figure out how from the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [baseline=-6mm,
  field/.style={font=\footnotesize,circle,fill=black, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm},
  wall/.style={font=\footnotesize,circle,draw=black, fill=white, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm}]
  \graph [simple necklace layout, node sep=2mm, node distance=0mm, nodes={field,as=},horizontal=C to B] {
  A[wall, label=above:1] -- B[label=below:2] -- C[label=below:3] -- A,
  C -- D[label=above:4],
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like for the labels to appear next to the edge on the outside of the graph. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please upload code which can compile

Comment: This compiles fine for me.

Comment: Please add a sketch of the expected output and probably a screenshot of your current output, as well. A clarification of the description "appear next to the edge on the outside of the graph"  would also be helpful. If I compile your document, I get the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9gpH.png. From the description in your question, I guess, you want something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5A0y.png If this assumption correct?

Comment: @leandriis, not quite. I can manipulate the node labels fine, I need to add labels to the edges. [My answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586090/233586) shows a solution I came up with, but I'm not sure how to customize it (e.g. changing the distance of the label or its position relative to the edge).

Comment: What does the :1, :2, etc. notation mean?

Comment: @BillNace Those are the labels on the nodes of the graph. The "above", "below", etc. that comes before is the position of the node label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `graphdrawing` may be overkill for this kind of example. Here is a solution with `tikz-cd`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{field/.style={circle,fill=black, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm},
  wall/.style={circle,draw=black, fill=white, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={}},row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
  |[field,label=above left:4]|\arrow[d,-,"f_{34}"'] & |[wall,label=above right:1]|\arrow[d,-,"f_{12}"]\arrow[dl,-]\\
  |[field,label=below left:3]|\arrow[r,-,"f_{23}"'] & |[field,label=below right:2]|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

You can add many options to the line labels by including `{<stuff>}` after the quotes `"<label>"`. For example, modifying the `f_{34}` label:

`\arrow[d,-,"f_{34}"'{pos=.7,xshift=-8pt,red}]`

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Is this a package that builds on top of tikz, or is it part of the tikz package itself? I don't remember seeing it in the PGF/tikz manual.

Comment: @scmartin: When you load `tikz-cd`, `tikz` loads automatically, but not the other way around. The [tikz-cd manual is here](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415548/quotes-with-tikz), I found that using the tikz quotes library `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}` gives me the basic functionality I need, as in the example below, but I don't really understand what the quotes library is doing, or how to customize position, etc. using this library. Any other methods to accomplish this, or explanations of how to manipulate the labels on the edges would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [baseline=-6mm, font=\small, label distance=-1mm,
  field/.style={circle,fill=black, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm},
  wall/.style={circle,draw=black, fill=white, minimum size=4mm, inner sep=0mm}]
  \graph [simple necklace layout, node sep=3mm, node distance=0mm, nodes={field,as=},horizontal=C to B] {
  A[wall, label=above right:1] --["\( f_{12} \)"] B[label=below right:2] --["\( f_{23} \)"] C[label=below left:3] -- A,
  C --["\( f_{34} \)"] D[label=above left:4],
  }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```