# TikZ node label is not being placed where I want it

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is the following MWE not placing the label along the correct angle?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={line width=1pt}]

  \coordinate (X) at (2,4) {};

  \foreach \x in { 100,107,114}    
    { 
      \node (tmp\x) at ($(X)+(\x:3)$) {};      
      \draw[orange!30,fill=orange!30] (X) -- (tmp\x);
    }

  \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,label=107:X] at (X) {};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,fill=none] (label/A) at ($(X)+(107:1.0)$) {Y};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `Y` has been placed where I expect and want the `X` to be.

Comment: labels and pins have *auto snap* issues to their compass anchors. There must be a few questions about this.

Comment: @percusse What do you mean by *auto snap*?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/how-can-i-force-tikz-pin-angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label` nodes are only placed in 45° steps, similar to nodes placed using the `auto` option.

You can disable this and get degree-accuracy by redefining the internal macro that is responsible for the snapping behaviour.

The following code (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85669/2552) does that:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}



\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}

\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)+90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={line width=1pt}]

  \coordinate (X) at (2,4) {};

  \foreach \x in { 100,107,114}    
    { 
      \node (tmp\x) at ($(X)+(\x:3)$) {};      
      \draw[orange!30,fill=orange!30] (X) -- (tmp\x);
    }

  \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,label=107:X] at (X) {};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,fill=none] (label/A) at ($(X)+(107:1.0)$) {Y};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So does this code change just the way `label`s and `pin`s work?  Or does it also change `auto`?  It seems to me that it's probably best to steer clear of using `label` and just create and place my own nodes for labeling purposes.  Nevertheless, thank you for the explanation of what's happening.