# How can I draw the following directed graph?

Tags: tikz-arrows

How can I make such a graph using tikz?

[image]

I can draw the circled nodes and the arrows, but I can't change their position. (e.g. the one that starts from node 1 and ends at node 3).

**Edit**: I would prefer straight arrows and not curved ones, just as in the drawing.

Comment: Did you read [TikZ parallel Edges between Nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85645/14500)?

Comment: You could use the `positioning` library. Especially handy for relative positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more straight forward approach may be using the `graph` library, (requires LuaLaTeX, though). Here is the code using `graph` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\tikz[>=Stealth]\graph[simple necklace layout, nodes={circle,minimum size=.7cm,draw}, node sep=1cm]{
  1,2,6,4,5,3;
  1->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt]3 -> 2, 3 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt]1 -> 2;
  3 -> 5 -> 6 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=-2pt]5, 5 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt] 6;
};
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Another possibility could be using a `matrix of nodes` as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,line width=.7pt]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm}]
{
& |(1)| 1 &   & |(2)| 2 & \\
&  & |(3)| 3 &  \\
& |(6)| 6 &   & |(5)| 5 & \\
&  & |(4)| 4 &   \\};
\draw (1)--(2);
\draw (3)--(2);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt},shorten <= -1pt] (3)--(1);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt},shorten <= -1pt] (1)--(3);
\draw (3) -- (5);
\draw (5) -- (6);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=2pt,yshift=-2pt},shorten >= -1pt] (4) -- (5);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-2pt,yshift=2pt},shorten >= -1pt] (5) -- (4);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt},shorten <= -1pt] (4) -- (6);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-2pt,yshift=-2pt},shorten <= -1pt] (6) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which now gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may use the positioning library of tikz as stated in the comments of your question. I used the shorten code in drawing arrows to connect them to the circle. Because, when you shift them, a white ugly space appears between the arrow and circle.

[image]

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=0.5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{0.25ex}

\node [draw , circle] (1) at (-0.5,3) {1};
\node [draw , circle] (2) at (0.5,3) {2};
\node [draw , circle] (3) at (0,2) {3};
\node [draw , circle] (4) at (0,0) {$4$};
\node [draw , circle] (5) at (0.5,1) {$5$};
\node [draw , circle] (6) at (-0.5,1) {$6$};

\draw [->] (1) -- (2);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=-\shift,yshift=-\shift}] (1) -- (3);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=\shift,yshift=\shift}] (3) -- (1);
\draw [->] (3) -- (2);

\draw [->] (3) -- (5);

\draw [->] (5) -- (6);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift}] (4) -- (5);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift}] (5) -- (4);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=-\shift,yshift=-\shift}] (6) -- (4);
\draw [->,shorten <=-1pt, transform canvas={xshift=\shift,yshift=\shift}] (4) -- (6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the first comment, I made what I wanted (Ι made sth similar to the original drawing)! Here's the code.

```
        \documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc,patterns,shapes.symbols,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations}

\begin{document}

%===Credits to JLDiaz for the following part=========

    \pgfdeclaredecoration{sl}{initial}{
        \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength-1sp]{
            \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        }
        \state{final}{
            \pgflineto{\pgfpointorigin}
        }
    }

    \tikzset{parallel arrow/.style={->, 
            shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm, 
            decoration={sl,raise=1mm},decorate}}
%===================================================================

    \tikzset{shorten arrow/.style = {->, shorten >=2 mm, shorten <=2mm}}



    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,3) circle (8pt)node[](1){1} ;

    \draw (3,6) circle (8pt)node[](4){4} ;
    \draw (6,3) circle (8pt)node[](3){3} ;
    \draw (0,0) circle (8pt)node[](2){2} ;
    \draw (3,3) circle (8pt)node[](5){5} ;
    \draw (3,0) circle (8pt)node[](6){6} ;

    \foreach \x in {1,3,5}
    \path (4) edge[shorten arrow] (\x);

    \foreach \x/\y in {1/2,2/1,2/6,6/2,5/6,6/5}
    \path (\x) edge [parallel arrow] (\y); 

\path (2)edge[shorten arrow] (5); 

\path (5)edge[shorten arrow] (3); 

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[%
row sep = 20mm, column sep = 20mm, % both optional, adapt as you please
cells={nodes={circle, draw}}, 
every arrow/.append style={shorten <= 1mm, shorten >= 1mm}] % both optional. Default connects the arrow directly to the circles
& 4 \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \arrow{dr} & \\
1 \arrow[shift left]{d} & 5 \arrow[shift left]{d} \arrow{r} & 3 \\
2 \arrow[shift left]{u} \arrow{ur} \arrow[shift left]{r} & 6 \arrow[shift left]{l} \arrow[shift left]{u} & 
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the default distance for `shift left` is not good for you, you can just add `=any_measure` to it. In this case, I would define a style `shifted` in order to change the value in just one place.