# pin angle not accepted

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a pin with a 45-degree angle.
For some reason, the angle is not accepted and is seen as the pin label:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.54]
 \path[draw,red,name path=thresh] (0,0.4) -- (4.0,0.4);
 \path[draw,blue,name path=four] (0,0) -- (4.0,1);
 \path[name intersections={of=four and thresh,name=newfour}];
 \node[style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3},
      pin={[pin edge={black,thick}]45:{cross}}] at (newfour-1) { };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

How can I fix this issue?

*Note: My pgf version is 2.10.*

Comment: Your code _works_ correctly with pgf 2.10, as you can check it [here](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/) for example (include `\pgfversion` command in the docuemnt to see that it has 2.10). Also [here](https://www.writelatex.com/121191kztmjm) too.

Comment: The problem must be elswhere then. I am using MacTex and when including \pgfversion the resukt is 2.10 as reported.

Comment: And I compile with pdflatex --shell-escape -enable-write18 $fullname

Comment: Pin angles are known to snap to certain angles. There must be a long thread about that. Here it is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/how-can-i-force-tikz-pin-angle

Comment: @percusse I am not sure the problem is due to the value of the angle. Replacing `45`by `right` give the same error.

Comment: Oh, OK. By the way I have no problems with CVS version.

Comment: @percusse BTW I saw the thread you mentioned it propose an alternative method to draw pin using `<coordinate a>!<dimension>!<angle>:<coordinate b>`> For some unknown reasons this piece of code doesn't work for me either. When I try the 2nd example of the section 13.5.4 of the pgf manual, i get the following error:
! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.
\coordinate (c) at ($ (a)!.25!(b) $); ?

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with your installation. That's a valid syntax provided that you are loading the `calc` library.

Comment: I do load the `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` library, is that the one? What check would you recommend doing to make sure the install is ok?

Comment: Problem solved with the help of the above discussion. Turns out that the use of `\usepackage[french]{babel}` was the culprit.

Comment: @percusse: how do I close this question now?

Comment: @vrleboss I've voted for closing. It should happen soon.