# How to rotate a TikZ label

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I need to place information below and to the right of a grid. I was not able to rotate the label text of a node. I ended up using `\rotatebox`, but is there a pure `TikZ` solution?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm] (1,1) grid (4,4);
  \node[label=below:\rotatebox{-90}{a long text}] at (2.5,1) {};
  \node[rotate=-90,label=below:rotate] at (1.5,0.5) {A};
  \node[label=right:a long text] at (4,3.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to use `label` in this situation. You just need to rearrange a bit the options and to fiddle around with the placement of the label:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm] (1,1) grid (4,4);
  \node[label={[label distance=0.5cm,text depth=-1ex,rotate=-90]right:a long text}] at (2.5,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the idea is to introduce the `rotate` option as an actual option to the label, not the node. Also, note the options `right` instead of `below` and `label distance`, which are necessary because the system will rotate the label relative to the node. Also, at this point the text might appear a bit off center, so a small hack is needed, to modify the vertical (rotated by -90 degrees at the same time!) position of the label text: `text depth=-1ex`.

[image]

Comment: In other presented solutions, the text box itself is centered. In your solution, the baseline is centered, which looks quite strange. Any fix?

Comment: @Josef: Voilà! `:)`

Comment: (I’d use `xshift` or `yshift` for correcting the label placement instead of fiddeling with the `text depth`, especially if you want to use (drawing/filling/referencing) the label later.) The `rotate` key rotates around the `anchor` of the label which is automatically set to `west` as you use `right` (or `east`) for the label’s direction. Instead of labeling an empty node, one should label a coordinate, an additional `label distance` can be provided: `\path (2.5,1) coordinate [label={[rotate=-90]right:{a long text}}];`

Comment: Another solution would be to [overwrite the automatically computed anchor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106796/16595) (e.g. `label={[rotate=-90,anchor=west]below:a long text}`, note the change of direction), though in this case, I probably would prefer [“real” nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115559/16595) for their flexibility.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Certainly, using a separate node is the most straightforward and easily customizable solution. I just took up the challenge to find out whether `label` is workable. Setting the anchor of the label was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks for giving it to me! `:)`

Answer (score 26):

You might prefer to use text nodes instead of labels. If you set `anchor=west`, the nodes will be 'left-aligned', and you can rotate the nodes as per usual.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm] (1,1) grid (4,4);
  \tikzset{anchor=west}
  \node at (4,1.5) {a long text};
  \node at (4,2.5) {a long text};
  \node at (4,3.5) {a long text};
  \node[rotate=-90] at (1.5,1) {a long text};
  \node[rotate=-90] at (2.5,1) {a long text};
  \node[rotate=-90] at (3.5,1) {a long text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]