# mirror node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I have to draw a diagram and would like to fit it on a page, thus i have not much space. Therefore I have to "stack" some gates, however it would be beneficial if I could put the outputs of the logic gate on the left and the inputs on the right side. Is there a way to flip a nodes shape (the label `&` still needs to be readable the right way round)?

Sketch of the issue (left what I would like, right alternative for the time beeing):
[image: sketch of the issue, left optimal, right current solution]

(I did not put much time into the simplified doodle, but I think it illustrates the issue, how to get the upper and gate)

**edit**: in my case a `3 input and` will do, however I am curious about solutions and not "workarrounds".

[MWE](https://www.writelatex.com/236463csqdql): Simply an `and` gate. Question, how do i turn the input and output sides arround (the order of `input n` anchors can be upside down)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [circuit logic IEC,
every circuit symbol/.style={
logic gate IEC symbol color=black,
fill=blue!20,draw=blue,very thick}]

    \node (and)[and gate]{};
    \draw (and.output) -- ++ (1,0);
    \draw (and.input 1) -- ++ (-1,0);
    \draw (and.input 2) -- ++ (-1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: done, see above for mwe

Comment: Alright, `rotate=180` and its clone `point left` also rotate the `&`. My fix would be to remove that `&` and simply put a `label` where it usually would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this is the idea of a solution. As the `label` option is only a wrapper for `append after command` we can use `\tikzlastnode` and extract the proper dimensions and place the `&` (or whatever symbol is used) appropriately.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

% from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106796/16595
\makeatletter
%\tikzset{anchor/.append code=\let\tikz@auto@anchor\relax}
\tikzset{inside/.code=\preto\tikz@auto@anchor{\pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}}
\tikzset{
  point left/.append style={
    label/.expanded={[inside, very thick, inner sep=2\pgflinewidth]south:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/and gate IEC symbol}},
    and gate IEC symbol=,
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  circuit logic IEC,
  every circuit symbol/.style={
    logic gate IEC symbol color=black,
    fill=blue!20,
    draw=blue,
    very thick
  }
]

  \node[and gate, point left] (and)[]{};
  \draw (and.output) -- ++ (-1,0);
  \draw (and.input 1) -- ++ (1,0);
  \draw (and.input 2) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thanks for the awnser. I have a hard time searching `preto` .Since I have no latex guide yet, could you either explain what `preto` does or where I can read about it/recommend a tex guide explaining it (preferebly available online).

Comment: found out that `preto`is part of the `etoolbox` to prepend code, however I am still wondering, why you changed the place where you supply the arguments to the `\node` command from after the `name`to before, is there a reason?

Comment: @ted The `inside` solution comes from the linked question. — No special reason but  my own style. There is no difference where you place the options for a node as long as they are between `node` (or `\node`) and the node  text `{}`. I like to gather them directly behind the `node`/`\node` text as I find the code more readable that way.