# swap a label to inner corner

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have below code section, the label "B" is displayed at the outside of the corner, how can we swap it to the inner corner? or any other good suggestion to label it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0,node distance=4em,
  box/.style={draw,anchor=west,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em},
]
  \node (A) [box] {A};
  \node (B) [below=of A.west,box,label=south west:B] {};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output picture is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And please do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than “user1234”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A label is supposed to exist *outside* a node so as to avoid confusion between the contents and label. The easiest IMO is to add an extra node for labelling.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0,node distance=4em,
  box/.style={draw,anchor=west,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em},
]
  \node (A) [box] {A};
  \node (B) [below=of A.west,box] {}node at ($(B.south west) +(0.15,0.15)$) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to @Harish's solution (which I think is easier) is to manually set the anchor of the label node. I follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106791/how-can-i-set-the-tikz-label-anchor-explicitly)  and define an `inside` key, which causes labels to be put "inside" a node:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{inside/.code=\preto\tikz@auto@anchor{\pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}}
\makeatother
```

Then one can pass this key to the `label` operation along with other options (e.g. `inner sep=1pt` to give extra padding to the label node).

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{inside/.code=\preto\tikz@auto@anchor{\pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0,node distance=4em,
  box/.style={draw,anchor=west,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em},
]
  \node (A) [box] {A};
  \node (B) [below=of A.west,box,label={[inside,inner sep=1pt]south west:B}] {};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This attempt is also an alternative solution when compared with @Harish and @Kevin's solutions (which I think is easy and simple). The first one need `calc`, the other needs `inside/.code`. This solution uses `anchor` and `at` of node position commands.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0.1mm,outer sep=0,node distance=4em,
  box/.style={draw,anchor=west,minimum width=10em,minimum height=3em},
]
  \node (A) [box] {A};
  \node (B) [below=of A.west, box] {}; 
  \node     [anchor=south west, at=(B.south west)]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```