# Putting text at bottom of ellipse in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rounded corners, draw, fill=gray!20 ,text height = 5cm,minimum     width=9cm] (main){All Feasible Schedules};
\node[ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text height =3cm, minimum width = 8cm] at (main.center)  (semi) {Semi-Active Schedules};
\node[ellipse, draw,fill=red!35, text height = 1.5cm, minimum width = 5cm] at (main.center) (active) {Active Schedules};
\node[ellipse, draw, fill=red!42,align=left, anchor=east, xshift=-0.5cm ] at (active.east) (non) {Non-delay\\Schedules};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives:

[image]

How can I get the text `semi-active schedules`, and `active schedules` to nestle snugly at the bottom of their respective ellipses?

Comment: Related: [How can I set the TikZ label anchor explicitly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106791/4778)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `label`s and `above` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rounded corners, draw, fill=gray!20 ,text height = 5.5cm,minimum     width=9cm] (main){All Feasible Schedules};
\node[ellipse, draw, fill=red!20, text height =3cm, minimum width = 8cm,label={[anchor=south,above=6.5mm]270:Semi-Active Schedules}] at (main.center)  (semi) {};
\node[ellipse, draw,fill=red!35, text height = 1.5cm, minimum width = 5cm,label={[anchor=south,above=6mm]270:Active Schedules}] at (main.center) (active) {};
\node[ellipse, draw, fill=red!42,align=left, anchor=east, xshift=-0.5cm ] at (active.east) (non) {Non-delay\\Schedules};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]