# Positioning text at node

Tags: pgfplots

This should be a simple question about positioning text with nodes using pgfplots.

To make a skew node line with text I'd use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = DPPH,
    xlabel = Applied Magnetic Field (I Guess) / G,
    xmax = 8,
    xmin = -8,
    ymax = 300,
    ymin = -300,
    ytick = \empty,
    xtick pos = left]

    \addplot[black, % Plotting the data
    no marks]
    table[x=xaxis,y=yaxis] {dpph2.dat};

    \node[coordinate,
    pin = {45:g factor = 1.96}
    ] at (0.2,224) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

for example.

To make a skew node with rotated text, where I can position the text about the node line using above, below, left, right or a combination of those, I'd change the `\node` part above to

```
\node[coordinate,
    pin = {[rotate=45]right:g factor = 1.96}
    ] at (-0.3,250) {};
```

My question: how do I use `above`, `below`, `right`, etc in the *first* code (without rotating the text as well as the node line)?  I tried things like `45right`, `45, right`, `[45]right`, but none of my guesses worked and I can't seem to find an example online.

**EDIT**

Here's what the first bit of code I put above gives me

[image]

and here's what I'd like to be able to do (just move where the text is with respect to the node line)

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` so that users can reproduce your problem and try to help you.

Comment: What is, e.g. `45 left` supposed to mean? Can you give an example/hand drawn sketch of what that should do?

Comment: I think that by default `pin` draws a line from center of `pin` node to `main` node. What you can select is where position the `pin` node but not it's anchor. But you can use a `label` node and draw a connection line later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Ab)using the code from Jake's answer to [How can I force TikZ pin angle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43912/how-can-i-force-tikz-pin-angle), we can define a new style for the pins that uses a label whose anchor we set to label the text, and an empty pin to draw the line. You supply the arguments like `[anchor for label]angle:text` to make it similar to the default pin usage. Presumably, there is some way to automatically choose the anchor based on the angle, but my TikZ-fu is not strong enough for that :-) Note that the `%` at the end of the lines are necessary because of how TikZ interprets spaces.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\tikzset{
    aligned pin/.style args={[#1]#2:#3}{
        pin={[%
            inner sep=0pt,%
            label={[%
                append after command={%
                    node[%
                        inner sep=0pt,%
                        at=(\tikzlastnode.#2),%
                        anchor=#1,%
                    ]{#3}%
                }%
            ]center:{}}%
        ]#2:{}}%
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = DPPH,
    xlabel = Applied Magnetic Field (I Guess) / G,
    xmax = 8,
    xmin = -8,
    ymax = 300,
    ymin = -300,
    ytick = \empty,
    xtick pos = left
    ]

    \node[coordinate,
    aligned pin={[west]45:g factor=1.96},
    ] at (0,0) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can `aligned pin` style be extended to allow for additional options of `pin`, for instance, `pin distance` or `pin edge=[dashed]`?

Comment: I would have in mind an identical only extended interface as pin: `aligned pin={[pin distance=<default=3ex>, pin anchor=<west,east,center,north,south>, pin edge=<options>]<angle>:text}` with `pin  anchor=center` returning to standard pin behaviour.