# Putting a title on a pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I put a title on the following pie chart?  I tried using `\stackon`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."


\begin{document}


%\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
%\stackon{%


\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}, pin distance=5mm]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node{Food \\ 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node{Rent and \\ Utilities \\ 35\%} (153:3);
\path (O) -- node[pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);
\path (O) -- node{Other \\ 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node{Car \\ 20\%} (324:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

%}{\bfseries\Longstack{David's Monthly Expenses}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:tables]?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer  Pie chart and tables are both convenient ways to organize data.  Does the `\stackon` command only apply to tables?

Comment: A pie chart is no table, so I am still wondering: Where's the table in your question?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer  No table.  May you suggest what `tag` to put on it?

Comment: I would remove the `tables` tag ;-)

Comment: TikZ doesn't provide special option for name of picture as ``pgfplots`` do. If you like to have name of picture as part of picture, than simple add one node in which you put picture name. But usual for this people use ``caption`` as part of float with picture. In case, that the your picture is directly in text, then again is normally use for its name derivative of ``caption`` (i.e.: ``\captionof``, if you use ``caption``package for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally pictures doesn't contain titles, this is task of figure captions, something like this:

```
text text text
    \begin{figure}
... picture ...
    \caption{David's Monthly Expenses}
    \label{fig:david-expences}
    \end{figure}
text text text
```

To add picture name on picture -- as I said in my comment, you need add a node with picture title:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={align=center},
     pin distance=9mm
                    ]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node{Food\\ 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node{Rent and\\ Utilities\\ 35\%} (153:3);
\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing\\ 5\%] {} (225:3);
\path (O) -- node{Other\\ 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node{Car\\ 20\%} (324:3);

\node[below=33mm of O] {\textbf{Title of picture}};%select one, which you more like
\node[right=33mm of O] {\textbf{Title of picture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, bots solution has nothing with tables, except if you like to put picture in table (what wasn't state in question). For your pie chart I use my answer on one of your previous question.

Comment: If I want it directly above the pie chart, and centered, do I issue the command `\node[above=33mm of O] {\textbf{Title of picture}};`?  (I guess `35mm` is just as good as `33mm`.)

Comment: Of course. That is matter of your taste. I just show two possibilities and how to do this (if you persist to name the pictures on this way).

Comment: I issue the command `\path (O) -- node[align=left,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);` and `TikZ` does not display what I expect.  The direction of the pin is not 225 degrees; the direction looks to be about 200 degrees.  Also, "5%" is not typed on the second line.  It seems that "\\" just removes the space between "Clothing" and "5%" to give `Clothing5%'.

Comment: What part of the command `\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing\\ 5\%] {} (225:3);` instructs `TikZ` to draw the pin from the `above right` corner of the node?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understood your question. This line in my MWE hasn't such instruction. It just say: center of node lie on 75% of distance from ``O`` and ``(225:3), pin is directed in azimuth ``225 degree`` for ``9mm`` from node. Label is below this point (default features of pin). For other possibilities see question ``http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246995/tikz-adjusting-pin-anchor``

Comment: Perhaps I changed the command.  This is the command that I have now. `\path (O) -- node[align=left,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);`.  Shouldn't "Clothing" and "5%" be put on separate lines?

Comment: They already in two lines, isn't it? I suggest you to form new question with provide MWE (on basis of my answer), show your problems. This comments become discussion what is not their intention.

Comment: I agree.  I will do that presently, and I will send you a "ping."

Comment: See the post  `A display in a pie chart that is not expected (or wanted)`.