# Using current path position in coordinate calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I often find myself writing code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (aNodeWithALongName) at (1,1) {a};
  \node (bNodeWithALongName) at (1,-1) {b};
  \node (c) at (0,0) {c};

  \draw[->] (aNodeWithALongName) -- (aNodeWithALongName -| c);
  \draw[->] (bNodeWithALongName) -- (bNodeWithALongName -| c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm drawing a path, and need to use the first point's position to compute the second point, and I would like to avoid repeating the `aNodeWithALongName`, like this for example:

```
  \draw[->] (aNodeWithALongName) -- (current -| c);
  \draw[->] (bNodeWithALongName) -- (current -| c);
```

And more complex stuff:

```
  \draw[->] ($(aNodeWithALongName)!.5!(bNodeWithALongName)$) -- (current -| c);
  \draw[->] (bNodeWithALongName) -- ++(0, 1cm) -- (current -| c);
```

Is there a syntax similar to that which I could use?

Comment: You might be better off using a `to path` defined as `\tikzset{my to/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}}` which you can use as `\draw[->] (aNodeWithALongName) to[my to] (c);`. See also [Tikz: purely vertical arrow from nodeA.south to nodeB.north](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87454)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution in [this TeX-SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53747/5699):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentcoordinate{\the\tikz@lastxsaved,\the\tikz@lastysaved}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (aNodeWithALongName) at (1,1) {a};
  \node (bNodeWithALongName) at (1,-1) {b};
  \node (c) at (0,0) {c};

  \draw[->] (aNodeWithALongName) -- (\currentcoordinate -| c);
  \draw[->] (bNodeWithALongName) -- (\currentcoordinate -| c);

  \draw[->] ($(aNodeWithALongName)!.5!(bNodeWithALongName)$) -- (\currentcoordinate -| c);
  \draw[->] (bNodeWithALongName) -- ++(0, 1cm) -- (\currentcoordinate -| c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```