# TikZ: how to memorize current coordinate into a variable during path creation

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, variable

I am creating electrical circuits using CircuiTikZ.

Quite often I need to connect to a certain point, which has been created previously using relative coordinates.

Right now I have to calculate these coordinates in advance. Instead, I want to be able to create a "coordinate variable" during the path creation, and use this variable later. Another way would be to extract the coordinates of a bipole terminal.

### Needed result

[image]

### Solution 1 (absolute coordinates)

This solution is unacceptable, because it leads to a very fragile code.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=$R$] ++(2,0) to [R=$R$] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) to [R=$R$] (4,1) -- (4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

### Solution 2 (using arcane math)

This is my current solution. Obviously it looks simple and no big deal here because it's an MWE, but in my schemes it gets pretty complicated.

```
\newcommand{\mylength}{2}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=$R$] ++(\mylength,0) to [R=$R$] ++(\mylength,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) to [R=$R$] (\mylength*2,1) -- (\mylength*2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

### Preferred solution №1 (anchors)

Unfortunately this does not work, because the anchor is on the *bipole itself*, and not on the terminal. (`\currentcoordinate` marco taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132926/106612)).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentcoordinate{\the\tikz@lastxsaved,\the\tikz@lastysaved}
\makeatother
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=$R$] ++(2,0) to [R=$R$, name=MyResistor] ++(2,0);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) to [R=$R$] (MyResistor.east |- \currentcoordinate) -- (MyResistor.east);
\end{circuitikz}
```

### Preferred solution №2 (memorizing coords in a variable)

This would be perfect.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=$R$] ++(2,0) to [R=$R$, name=MyResistor] ++(2,0) [\MyVariable=\currentcoordinate];
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) to [R=$R$] (\MyVariable |- \currentcoordinate) -- (\MyVariable);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Can't you just replace in your last snippet `[\MyVariable=\currentcoordinate]` by `coordinate (X)` and use `X` thereafter? You would help us a lot if you would provide a complete MWE for that, which we could just copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named coordinates already exist in TikZ.  They even have nicer syntax than what you propose.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [R=$R$] ++(2,0) to [R=$R$, name=MyResistor] ++(2,0) coordinate (lr);
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) coordinate (ul) to [R=$R$] (lr |- ul) -- (lr);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also just draw the whole thing on a single path and not use named coordinates at all.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw ( 0,0) to [R=$R$]
      ++( 2,0) to [R=$R$]
      ++( 2,0) to [short]
      ++( 0,1) to [R,l_=$R$]
      ++(-4,0) to[short]
        ( 0,0) -- cycle;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `coordinate` is exactly what I needed.