# Tikz: How to combine orthogonal edge syntax with coordinate calculation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, calculations, coordinates, node-connections

I'm trying to combine the syntax for orthogonal edges `(p |- q)` with the syntax for calculation relative coordinates `($ (a) + (1,0) $)`. Example:

```
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- node2.north);
```

However, I get an error:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named ($ (node1 is known.
```

There is an obvious work-around in this case, but for educational purpose I'd like to understand why this syntax does not work, and how to solve the problem in general? Intuitively the documentation would suggest that I can simply combine these two syntaxes.

**Update -- MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,  0) (node1) {Hello};
\node at (0, -2) (node2) {World};

% working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( node1.south |- node2.north);

% not working:
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) to ( ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) |- node2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable MWE including `\documentclass` and the appropriate `packages` that sets up the problem, and shows what you have tried. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Most likely, `node1` has never been defined before.

Comment: Try moving the ( following `to` to the front of `node2.north` in the last not working line.

Comment: @Jesse: This compiles but is not semantically equivalent (you are connecting 3 points instead of 2, and the middle point is only meant as a means for construction, not as a point for drawing).

Comment: @percusse: Yes indeed, if only I knew that `!.5!` has anything to do with coordinate calculation :).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm trying to answer my own question despite severe lack of knowledge...

After a closer examination of related problems, I have found that combining [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53747/30658) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29781/30658) answer serves as an appropriate answer to my question as well (my question might be marked as duplicate although the respective questions go into a slightly different direction).

For future Tikz learners I add an example of the probably most convenient workaround, i.e., introducing temporary node names:

```
\draw ($ (node1.south) + (1,0) $) coordinate(temp) to (temp |- node2.north);
```

Comment: Indeed I voted for duplicate for Andrew's answer in `that` answer