# Tikz: purely vertical arrow from nodeA.south to nodeB.north

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, nodes

I have the following tikz code

```
% compilation command: pdflatex --jobname=Diag-f1 Diag.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfrealjobname{Diag}
\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{Diag-f1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3em]
\node(G)[rectangle,fill=red!5,draw=red,text width=5cm]{};
\node(H)[below of=G]{H};
\node(H1)[left of=H]{H1};
\node(H2)[right of=H]{H2};
\draw[->](G.south)-|(H1.north);
\draw[->](G.south)--(H.north);
\draw[->](G.south)-|(H2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I am not happy with the two arrows going from G.south to H1.north and H2.north. Because of the `-|` command, there is a spurious horizontal line. How can I achieve the same result without this annoying horizontal line? `\draw[->](G.south)--(H1.north);` is not a solution. There are available tricks but I may have missed an obvious solution here.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The line is normal: `-|` means: draw an horizontal line, then a vertical.

You could use this:

```
\draw[->] (G.south -| H1.north) -- (H1.north)
```

That will compute the intersection between a vertical line through `H1.north` and a horizontal one through `G.south`, and then draw a line from it to `H1.north`

Answer (score 29):

I like the use of `to` paths.

Advantage: The target coordinate/node has only to be given once.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    *|/.style={
        to path={
            (perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={(\tikztostart)},
                                 vertical line through={(\tikztotarget)})
            % is the same as (\tikztostart -| \tikztotarget)
            % but just to be safe: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29781/16595
            -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3em]
\node(G)  [rectangle,fill=red!5,draw=red,text width=5cm] {};
\node(H)  [below of=G] {H};
\node(H1) [left of=H]  {H1};
\node(H2) [right of=H] {H2};
\draw[->,*|] (G.south) to     (H1.north);
\draw[->]    (G.south) --     (H.north);
\draw[->]    (G.south) to[*|] (H2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

For various different possibilities of this (and without the need to declare the anchors), you can define more styles like this. This is also part of my `paths.ortho` library (see my user info).

Note that this (as well as the original answer, see above) does currently not take the current transformation in account and just uses the anchors `.north`, `.south`, `.east` and `.west`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@ortho@preflush
\tikz@ortho@preflushtrue
\let\tikz@origtotarget\pgfutil@empty
\tikzset{
  |-/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  -|/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  *|/.style={to path={%
    \pgfextra
      \iftikz@shapeborder
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \ifdim\pgf@y>\tikz@lasty\relax
          \edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.north}%
        \else
          \edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.south}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \endpgfextra
    (perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={(\tikztostart)},
                 vertical line through={(\tikztotarget)}) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
  }},
  *-/.style={to path={%
    \pgfextra
      \iftikz@shapeborder
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \ifdim\pgf@x>\tikz@lastx\relax
          \edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.east}%
        \else
          \edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.west}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \endpgfextra
    (perpendicular cs: vertical line through={(\tikztostart)},
                     horizontal line through={(\tikztotarget)}) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
  }},
  |*/.style={to path={%
    \pgfextra
      \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
      \iftikz@shapeborder
        \let\tikz@origtotarget\tikztotarget
        \ifdim\pgf@y>\tikz@lasty\relax
          \edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.south}%
        \else
          \edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.north}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \endpgfextra
    (\tikztostart) -- (perpendicular cs: vertical line through={(\tikztostart)},
                                         horizontal line through={(\tikztotarget)})
    \tikztonodes \ifx\tikz@origtotarget\pgfutil@empty\else\iftikz@ortho@preflush(\tikz@origtotarget)\fi\fi
  }},
  -*/.style={to path={%
    \pgfextra
      \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
      \iftikz@shapeborder
        \let\tikz@origtotarget\tikztotarget
        \ifdim\pgf@x>\tikz@lastx\relax
          \edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.west}%
        \else
          \edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.east}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \endpgfextra
    (\tikztostart) -- (perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={(\tikztostart)},
                                         vertical line through={(\tikztotarget)})
    \tikztonodes \ifx\tikz@origtotarget\pgfutil@empty\else\iftikz@ortho@preflush(\tikz@origtotarget)\fi\fi
  }},
  node as new start/.is if=tikz@ortho@preflush
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[nodes={shape=rectangle, draw, minimum width=+1.5cm, minimum height=+1cm}]
  \node (a)                {A};
  \node (b) at (  .5, 2  ) {B};
  \node (c) at ( 2.5,- .2) {C};
  \node (d) at (- .5,-2  ) {D};
  \node (e) at (-2.5,  .2) {E};
\end{scope}
\tikzset{nodes={auto,font=\small\ttfamily}}
\path[->] (a) edge[*|]                 (b)
          (b) edge[*|] node {*|}       (a)
          (a) edge[*-]                 (c)
          (c) edge[*-] node[swap] {*-} (a)
          (a) edge[|*]                 (d)
          (d) edge[|*] node[swap] {|*} (a)
          (a) edge[-*]                 (e)
          (e) edge[-*] node       {-*} (a)
          %
          {[every edge/.append style=blue]
            {[|-]
              (e) edge (b)
                  edge (d)}
            {[-|]
              (b) edge (c)
              (d) edge (c)}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=rectangle, draw, minimum width=+1cm, minimum height=+1cm}]
  \node (a)              {A};
  \node (b) at ( .25, 2) {B};
  \node (c) at (1.25,-0) {C};
  \draw (a) to [|*] (b) to (c);

  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, node as new start=false]
    \node (a)              {A};
    \node (b) at ( .25, 2) {B};
    \node (c) at (1.25,-0) {C};
    \draw (a) to [|*] (b) to (c);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={rectangle,draw,anchor=west,minimum height=+1cm}]
\node (rechteck1)[minimum width=+3cm] at (1,5){};
\node (rechteck2)[minimum width=+2cm] at (1,3){};

\draw [->] (rechteck1) to[*|] (rechteck2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you make it work the other way? (drawing H to G), using the x-coordinate of H but the y-coordinate of G?

Comment: @JasonS Are you interested in something like [what my German answer on TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1289/vertikale-verbindung-zwischen-zwei-ungleich-groen-elementen/1295) shows? The same code is used in my `paths.ortho` library (using files [1](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex) and [2](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex)).

Comment: Hmm... not sure, still trying to understand what this code is doing + what I need. I essentially want a vertical (or horizontal) line between the given edges of shapes A and B, through a point C between them. (sometimes point C is an edge on shape A or B.)

Comment: @JasonS The `-|` in this answer corresponds to `*|` in `paths.ortho` with the added bonus that you don't need to specify anchors. I don't know what the role of a point C should be. A vertical or horizontal line between two nodes with those keys in `paths.ortho` is fully defined. Maybe you can ask a separate question?