# Drawing PQ-trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I need to draw PQ-trees in LaTeX which look like these:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D4cIk0x.png]

I tried trees in tikz but I had two problems:

- partially shade rectangles
- use vertical pointers from children to the parent, if the parent is a rectangle

I'm wondering whether tikz-trees is the easiest way to go or whether you would recommend using something else?

Comment: To partially shade the rectangles, check out the `patterns` library. See, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns. For vertical pointers you want to use the `|-` syntax. See, for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87454/tikz-purely-vertical-arrow-from-nodea-south-to-nodeb-north

Comment: Thanks, I managed to draw vertical pointers and I tried to define my own pattern - but I don't see how I can partially fill a node by defining my own pattern?

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package for the placement of the nodes. The advantage here is that they get automatically positioned so that they not overlap.

For the nodes I defined three styles:

- `tria` for the triangle node, it uses the `isosceles triangle` shape (you can specify width and height);
- `rect` for the rectangular node, as an argument, it needs the the number of children it has (including the `…` node) so that it can be stretched correctly covering its children widthwise;
- `circ` for the circular node;
- `dots` for the node with the `\ldots` in it, the `\ldots` are given via the `content` key (a `forest` key).

Furthermore,

- the `patt` key is used to pattern only a part of a shape via the `path picture` option; as I ran intro problems with the TikZ version (both coordinates `@aux1` and `@aux2` lie in the defaulting center) the (faster and more convenient) PGF version of this works. The argument is `<start of the pattern>:<end of the pattern>`, which are the horizontal ratio.
- The `*|` is used to draw only a vertical line to the parent node (this can actually be included in the `rect` style).
- The values of the `normal width` and the `normal height` key is used for the sizes of the nodes.

---

In the `rect` style one can find

```
minimum width=
     (#1  )*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/normal width})
   + (#1+1)*(\forestove{s sep})
   - (#1  )*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})
```

which works very well, though I initially had a different setup

As the `rect` style gets the number of children `#1`, the width is set to `#1 * width` which takes up the total width of the children. So far so good. 
I initially had here `#1 - 1` times the `s sep` (six children have five spaces between them), though `#1 + 1` seems more correct, otherwise the children protrude more or less over the horizontal sides of the `rect`angle (or the `rect` is not as wide as its children).

There seems more to be about the spacing between nodes. If one sets different `normal width` and `normal height` values this spacing is thrown off. I suspect that the height of nodes somehow have an influence on the `s sep`, the horizontal spacing between nodes.

#### Further improvement …

… can be achieved by automatizing the process. The triangular nodes only come in pairs with the dots between them and are then patterned the same way.

Also, `forest` has probably the ability to read the number of children in advance so that it can set the width of the `rect`angle automatically.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,patterns}
\forestset{
  *|/.style={
    parent anchor=south,
    for descendants={
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor-|.child anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      }
    }
  },
  normal width/.initial=.5cm,
  normal height/.initial=.5cm,
  every forest node/.style={
    draw,
    minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/normal width},
    minimum height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/normal height},
    inner sep=+0pt,
    anchor=south,
  },
  tria/.style={
    every forest node,
    shape=isosceles triangle,
    shape border rotate=90,
    isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
%    isosceles triangle stretches=true
  },
  rect/.style={
    every forest node,
    shape=rectangle,
    minimum width=(#1)*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/normal width})+(#1+1)*(\forestove{s sep})-(#1)*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}),
  },
  rect/.default=3,
  circ/.style={
    every forest node,
    shape=circle
  },
  dots/.style={
    no edge,
    content=\ldots,
    every forest node,
    shape=rectangle,
    draw=none,
  },
  patt/.style args={#1:#2}{
    node options={
      /tikz/path picture={
        \pgfsetfillpattern{north east lines}{black}
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners
          {\pgfpointlineattime{#1}
            {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north west}}
            {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}}
          {\pgfpointlineattime{#2}
            {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
            {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south east}}}
         \pgfusepath{fill}
%      \draw[green,ultra thick] (path picture bounding box.north west) -- coordinate[pos={#1}] (@aux1) (path picture bounding box.north east)
%                               (path picture bounding box.south west) -- coordinate[pos={#2}] (@aux2) (path picture bounding box.south east);
%      \fill[draw,pattern=north east lines] (@aux1) rectangle (@aux2);
%%      \fill[blue] (@aux1) circle (2pt);
%%      \fill[red] (@aux2) circle (1pt);
      }
    }
  },
  patt/.default=0:1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={child anchor=north}
  [,circ,
    [, tria]
    [, dots]
    [, tria]
    [, rect=6, patt=.5:1, *|, alias=XY
      [, tria]
      [, dots]
      [, tria]
      [, tria, patt]
      [, dots]
      [, tria, patt, alias=XX]
    ]
    [, tria, patt]
    [, dots]
    [, tria, patt]
    [, rect=6, patt=0:.5, *|
      [, tria, patt]
      [, dots]
      [, tria, patt]
      [, tria]
      [, dots]
      [, tria]
    ]
  ]
% just to show that they are aligned correctly
  \draw[opacity=.5] (XY.south east) -- (XX.right corner);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]