# How to modify the cell dimensions in tikzcd?

Tags: alignment, tikz-cd, width, commutative-diagrams, phantom

**Code:**

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=gray}}]
    \text{Math is excellent!} \ar[r, rightarrow] \ar[d, leftarrow]
        & \text{w} \ar[d, rightarrow]\\
    \text{w} \ar[u, rightarrow] \ar[r, leftarrow]
        & \text{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Requirement:** I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

1. I know that Case 1 is not possible since the columns (and rows) are formed by centering the cells.
2. So I try to implement Case 2 which does seem achievable. In particular, I am trying to do this:

   - Make the width of the cells in a column equal.
   - Then somehow write on that cell *at a specific place*. (Left aligned on the top right, and right aligned on the bottom left.)

**Note:** I deliberately write *"at a specific place"*, and not just the special cases of left and right alignments.

Can this be done? (I thought of using `\phantom`. But that obviously gives crude results in this case.)

I know that how to modify the arrow anchor points so it is not a problem.

Comment: Is `tikz-cd` mandatory for your future use? If not, I think that a simple Ti*k*Z graph would be a better solution.

Comment: I am trying to avoid TikZ since it seems overwhelmingly complicated to me than the friendly and simple `tikz-cd`.

Comment: I can hear that, but if you're not to draw more complicated graph than this one, it's pretty straightforward in plain Ti*k*Z and would be a pain to achieve in `tikz-cd`. Hope someone will find a solution for you.

Comment: Can you extend what you mean with *at a specific place*? Both your cases can be done the way you've drawn them.

Comment: Could be great if you accepted an answer below, stating that your question has been solved.

Comment: @SebGlav I haven't yet dabbled in the complexities of the codes given in the answers, but have upvoted them. So I don't want to *pick* one above others yet. But please know that I believe that the answers are great!

Comment: Your choice, but actually, letting a question open like this means that you're still looking for a fitting answer. It lets other members to check and eventually try once again to answer. But here, your problem seems to be solved (even for the `tikz-cd` original demand), so that letting the question open is misleading, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

Just to let you know how to do this in plain Ti*k*Z, even if this is not what you're asking for:

[image: four nodes and arrows]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            node distance = 2cm and 5cm,
            every node/.style = {
                rectangle,
                draw,
                inner sep = 5pt,
                minimum size = 1cm},
            > = {Straight Barb}
            ]
        \node[left] (A) {Math is excellent!};
        \node[right, right= of A] (B) {w};
        \node[below = of A.east, anchor = east] (C) {w};
        \node[below = of B.west, anchor = west] (D) {Pythagoreans kill someone!};
        
        \path[->]
            (A) edge (B)
            (B.south) edge (D.north-|B)
            (D) edge (C)
            (C.north) edge (A.south-|C);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are better ways to do this (but more complex), so I just wrote a *simple* code.

Comment: I guess it's my time to try my hands on Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `tikz-cd` solution. The idea is to use `\fcolorbox` to draw the boxes around the text, and `\llap` and `\rlap` to control the arrow placement. Box color is controlled globally with `\cdboxcolor`, set to gray.

Define new commands `\leftbox`, `\rightbox` and `\cdbox`:

`\leftbox{<dim>}{<text>}` places `<text>` in a box that is shifted left so the `tikzcd` arrow is aimed as if the box had width `<dim>` instead of its actual width. `\rightbox` is defined analogously. `\cdbox{<text>}` does not shift.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}

\newcommand{\cdboxcolor}{gray}
\newcommand{\leftbox}[2]{\hspace{#1}\llap{\fcolorbox{\cdboxcolor}{white}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\rightbox}[2]{\rlap{\fcolorbox{\cdboxcolor}{white}{#2}}\hspace{#1}}
\newcommand{\cdbox}[1]{\fcolorbox{\cdboxcolor}{white}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={inner sep=0pt}}]
    \leftbox{1cm}{Math is excellent!} \ar[r, rightarrow] \ar[d, leftarrow]
        & \cdbox{w} \ar[d, rightarrow]\\
    \cdbox{w} \ar[u, rightarrow] \ar[r, leftarrow]
        & \rightbox{1cm}{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but is there any way to adjust the boxes anchors in order to align them to the left or to the right like we do with Ti*k*Z?

Comment: @SebGlav: I couldn't think of an elementary way of doing this. Trying to adjust the anchors in `tikz-cd` seems much more complicated than learning how to do this with `TikZ`, as you suggested. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by

> **Note:** I deliberately write *"at a specific place"*, and not just the special cases of left and right alignments.

What other kind of alignments are there?

## Case 1

Case 1 is actually the easiest.

> 1. I know that Case 1 is not possible since the columns (and rows) are formed by centering the cells.

No, they aren't. They are aligned by their coordinate systems.
[The rows align by *y* = 0 and the columns align by *x* = 0.](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#sec-20.3.1)
([Though, they are some pitfalls.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/666817/16595))

Since every node is placed by default at (0, 0) you can just change its anchor.
By default, all nodes in a `matrix of math nodes` are placed at their `base` anchor.

This means the columns are horizontally centered and the rows are aligned by their baseline. By changing this to `base west` or `base east` we can enforce left or right alignment.

In the second diagram I've added some `xshift`ing that changes the position “at a specifical place”.

I'm using my `ext.paths.ortho` library which provides handy styles following question and answer to “[Tikz: purely vertical arrow from nodeA.south to nodeB.north](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87454)”.
The shortcut `*|` stands for `only vertical second` and `|*` stands for `only vertical first`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{strut without depth/.style={text depth=+0pt, text height=+\ht\strutbox}}
\tikzcdset{
  column align/.is choice,
  @column align/.style n args={2}{column align/#1/.style={anchor={#2}}},
  @column align/.list={{left}{base west},{right}{base east},{center}{base}},
  colspec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\pgfmathresult{0},
    /utils/temp/.code={%
      \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathresult+1}}%
      \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/column \pgfmathresult/.append style={
                     /tikz/commutative diagrams/column align/##1}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}}}

\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={strut without depth, nodes={draw=gray}},
  math mode=false,
  /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts,
  colspec={right, left},
]
  Math is excellent!           \ar[r, rightarrow]
                               \ar[d, *|, leftarrow]
& w                            \ar[d, |*, rightarrow] \\
  w                            \ar[r, leftarrow]
& Pythagoreans killed someone!
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={strut without depth, nodes={draw=gray}},
  math mode=false,
  /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts,
  colspec={right, left},
]
  Math is excellent!           \ar[r, rightarrow]
                               \ar[d, *|, leftarrow]
& |[xshift=1cm]|   w           \ar[d, |*, rightarrow] \\
  |[xshift=-.5cm]| w           \ar[r, leftarrow]
& Pythagoreans killed someone!
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Case 2

Again, with purely left, right and center alignment, this is possible.

This is basically the same as case 1 just with a fitted node around the actual contant which uses my [`ext.node-families` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227/16595).

I've added a third and centered column to highlight why `from'` and/or `to'` is necessary to switch between the smaller nodes and the bigger drawn ones.

We could even invert that toggle (by naming the inner nodes with a `'` and the drawn nodes without one).

This uses a custom `fit` key (that also only scans one node) because TikZ-CD uses a special `asymmetrical rectangle` shape.
For other alignments than left/right/center, i.e. as above with `xshift`, an adjustment to the `fit` key is necessary.

We could also do something like I did in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660803/16595) for “[Make two nodes occupy the space of one node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/660784)” where you can just go haywire with your placement and place a subnode inside it and have it act almost like a proper node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
  @column align/.style n args={4}{
    column align/#1/.style={
      anchor={#2}, /tikz/commutative diagrams/@make box of column/.style={
        anchor={#3}, at={(\tikzlastnode.#4)}}}},
  column align/.is choice,
  @column align/.list={
    {left}  {base west}{real west}  {real west},
    {right} {base east}{real east}  {real east},
    {center}{base}     {real center}{real center}},
  colspec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\pgfmathresult{0},
    /utils/temp/.code={%
      \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathresult+1}}%
      \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/column \pgfmathresult/.append style={
                     /tikz/commutative diagrams/column align/##1}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}},
  make box of column/.style={
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, minimum size=+0pt,
    commutative diagrams/fit=\tikzlastnode,name=\tikzlastnode',
    node family/width=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
    commutative diagrams/@make box of column,
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[
      commutative diagrams/column box/.try,to path={
        ([xshift=+.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=+.5\pgflinewidth]\tikztostart)
        rectangle([xshift=+-.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=+-.5\pgflinewidth]%
          \tikztotarget)}](\tikzlastnode.north east)}},
  make column box/.style={
    append after command={
      [every node/.code=]node[commutative diagrams/make box of column]{}}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  fit/.code={% tikz-cd uses an asymmetrical rectangle …
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{west}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{east}}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/text width/.expanded=+\the\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{base}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{north}}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/text height/.expanded=+\the\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{south}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{#1}}{base}}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/text depth/.expanded=+\the\pgf@y}},
  from'/.code=\edef\tikzcd@ar@start{\tikzcd@ar@start'},
  to'/.code=\edef\tikzcd@ar@target{\tikzcd@ar@target'}}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho,ext.node-families,fit}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={
    text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em,% \strut without depth
    nodes={commutative diagrams/make column box}},
  math mode=false,
  /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts,
  colspec={right, left, center}
]
  Math is excellent!
    \ar[r, rightarrow]
    \ar[d, *|, leftarrow]
& w \ar[d, |*, rightarrow] \rar[from', to']
& Foo \\
  w \ar[r, leftarrow]
& Pythagoreans killed someone!
& Baaaaaaaaaar
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Who told you Case 1 is not possible?
Of course, it is, with `tikz-cd`, without using hacking!
You may 1) use `\tikztostart` (starting point) and `\tikztotarget` (ending point); or 2) name a node; and then use them in `to path` or `from`.

Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
Solution with node names and \verb|from|/\verb|to|:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    cells={nodes={draw=gray}},
    /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
    ]
    |[alias=mathis]|\text{Math is excellent!}\ar[r]\ar[d, leftarrow, from={mathis.south -| secondw}] &
      |[alias=firstw]|\text{w}\ar[d, to={Pytha.north -| firstw}]\\
    |[alias=secondw]|\text{w}\ar[r, leftarrow] &   
      |[alias=Pytha]|\text{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Solution with node names and \verb|to path|:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    cells={nodes={draw=gray}},
    /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
    ]
    |[alias=mathis]|\text{Math is excellent!}\ar[r]\ar[d, leftarrow, to path={(mathis.south -| secondw) -- (secondw)}] &
      |[alias=firstw]|\text{w}\ar[d, to path={ -- (Pytha.north -| firstw)}]\\
    |[alias=secondw]|\text{w}\ar[r, leftarrow] & 
      |[alias=Pytha]|\text{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Solution with \verb|\tikztostart|, \verb|\tikztotarget| and \verb|to path|:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    cells={nodes={draw=gray}},
    /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
    ]
    \text{Math is excellent!}\ar[r]\ar[d, leftarrow, to path={(\tikztostart.south -| \tikztotarget) -- (\tikztotarget)}] &
      \text{w}\ar[d, to path={-- (\tikztotarget.north -| \tikztostart)}]\\
    \text{w}\ar[r, leftarrow] & \text{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
    \end{tikzcd}
\]

Mixed:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    cells={nodes={draw=gray}},
    /tikz/column 1/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
    ]
    |[alias=first]|\text{Math is excellent!}\ar[r]\ar[d, leftarrow, from={first.south -| second}] &
      \text{w}\ar[d, to path={-- (\tikztotarget.north -| \tikztostart)}]\\
    |[alias=second]|\text{w}\ar[r, leftarrow] & \text{Pythagoreans killed someone!}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at Section 2.4 here, for more info: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb43-1/tb133duck-tikz-cd.pdf.