# Rectilinear coordinates in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

In the diagram

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            A \ar[rr, ""' name=x] &&[2cm] B\\
            &C   \ar[ur, "" name=y, out=0, in=-135]
                    \ar[from=x, to=y, Rightarrow]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

it would certainly be nicer if the double struck arrow was perfectly vertical, either by starting at `(x -| y)` or ending at `(x |- y)`. But tikz-cd seems not to like the `-|`-syntax. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, TikZ-cd uses the `to` path operator in its implementation of `\ar` (which is why `out = 0, in = -135` works as it does). You can always just use [`to path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#tikz/to:path) to manually draw an arrow:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[labels={draw,help lines}]
  A \ar[rr, ""' name=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[to path=(x) -- (x|-y), Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[to path=(x-|y) -- (y), Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

In the above example, I've chosen to show the labels, i.e. the nodes you place along an arrow, because they have a size even if you specify empty text `""`.
This has an effect on the `-|` and `|-` coordinate specifications since they only use the center of the nodes to find the intersecting coordinate.
This is the reason the red arrow ends not at the same height as the blue and the blue one doesn't start at the same place as the red one.

I would use coordinates in place of the nodes and just shorten the arrow a bit:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/name*/.style={name={#1},shape=coordinate}]
  A \ar[rr, "" name*=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name*=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, to path=(x) -- (x|-y), Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, to path=(x-|y) -- (y), Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

---

Now, I don't think it would be wise to explicitly write down each `to path`.
We should use styles for that. I did this before in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87463/16595) to [Tikz: purely vertical arrow from nodeA.south to nodeB.north](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87454/16595) and a bit more complicated version are part of the `ext.paths.ortho` library of my `tikz-ext` package.

In its most simple form they are

```
\tikzset{
  |*/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  *|/.style={to path={(\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget)--(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  -*/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  *-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget)--(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}}
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/name*/.style={name={#1},shape=coordinate}]
  A \ar[rr, "" name*=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name*=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, from=x, to=y, |*, Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, from=x, to=y, *|, Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
```

With the mentioned `ext.paths.ortho` library, the available `to path`s try to take the border of the start and end points in consideration.

```
\begin{tikzcd}[labels={draw,help lines}, /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts]
  A \ar[rr, ""' name=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[from=x, to=y, |*, Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[from=x, to=y, *|, Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Here `/tikz/ortho/install shortcuts` actually defines `|*` et al to be shortcuts to `only vertical first` etc. which are always available with the library.

---

If you need the vertical line to be a specific distance away from the curved arrow you will need to use the `intersections` library.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[labels={draw,help lines}]
  A \ar[rr, ""' name=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[to path=(x) -- (x|-y), Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[to path=(x-|y) -- (y), Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/name*/.style={name={#1},shape=coordinate}]
  A \ar[rr, "" name*=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name*=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, to path=(x) -- (x|-y), Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, to path=(x-|y) -- (y), Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}

\tikzset{
  |*/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  *|/.style={to path={(\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget)--(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  -*/.style={to path={--(\tikztostart-|\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  *-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart|-\tikztotarget)--(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}}
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/name*/.style={name={#1},shape=coordinate}]
  A \ar[rr, "" name*=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name*=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, from=x, to=y, |*, Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[shorten=2pt, from=x, to=y, *|, Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[labels={draw,help lines}, /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts]
% /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts overwrites previously defined |*, *|, -*, *-
  A \ar[rr, ""' name=x]                & &[2cm] B\\
& C \ar[ur, "" name=y, out=0, in=-135]
    \ar[from=x, to=y, |*, Rightarrow, red]
    \ar[from=x, to=y, *|, Rightarrow, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Ask one question and get answers to 10 more questions that I hadn't even thought about!

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Qrrbrbirlbel outlines a general solution for using `-|` notation in `tikz-cd`. A somewhat simpler solution is just to add an additional column and draw a shortened down arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}
            A \ar[rrr] && \ar[d, Rightarrow, shorten >=3.5mm] & B\\
            & C \ar[urr, out=0, in=-135] & {}
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```