# TikZ grouping expressions in calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I had to do some calculations like:

```
\node (A) {A};
\node (b) at (x,y) {B};

((A) + (B))*2
```

However I could not figure out how to group it in a calc statement, I tried `($((A)+(B))*2$)` and `(${(A)+(B)}*2$)`. How can I express this? (Currently I use `($(A)*2+(B)*2$)`, so I have to adjust the factor in two places)

A similar issue occurs with the `|-` Operator. I can use it in calculations as long as I don't try pulling of mathematic operations on one of the operands. Is there a way to achieve `($((A)+(B)) |- (4,7)$)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first question, you can nest coordinate calculations to first calculate `A+B`, and then multiply this result by 2:

```
\node at ($2*($(A)+(B)$)$) {C};
```

Another way is mentioned by Qrrbrbirlbel in a comment below:

```
\node at ([scale=2]$(A)+(B)$) {C};
```

For the second question, see Andrew Stacey's answer on [Combining |- and !.5! in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/combining-and-5-in-tikz/29781#29781). In short, use two pairs of braces around the calculation of the first coordinate:

```
\node at ({{$(A)+(B)$}} |- 4,7) {D};
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3); 

\node (A) at (0,1) {A};
\node (B) at (1,0) {B};

\node at ($2*($(A)+(B)$)$) {C};

\node at ({{$(A)+(B)$}} |- 4,3) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another possibility for `C` is `\node at ([scale=2]$(A)+(B)$) {C};`.

Comment: Indeed that was the answer I was mentioning. Great.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, I added that to my answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

The `let` action is very useful in theses cases or for more complex calculations:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,1) {A};
\node (B) at (1,0) {B};
\path let \p1=($(A)+(B)$), \p2=($2*(\p1)$) in node at (\p2) {C};
\path let \p1=($(A)+(B)$), \p2=(\p1 |- 4,7) in node at (\p2) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```