# How to define node / coordinate with perpendicular

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

How to define / save a point for later usage with x/y-coordinates of other points?
I tried to use the perpendicular coordinate system shortform `|-` and `-|` but could not define points that way.

In bigger pictures I would prefer using a node instead of expressions like `(A -| B)` all the time. 
Especially with more complicated "calculations" for relative positions of points this could get tedious.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines, step=0.5cm] (-2.5,0) grid (0,2.5);
    \node (A) at (-0.5,0.5) {A};
    \node (B) at (-2,2) {B};

    % \node (someName) at (A -| B);

    \draw (A |- B) node {C};
    \draw (A -| B) node {D};
    \draw (A |- B) edge (A -| B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do exactly what you're trying, you just have to specify a node text:

```
\node (someName) at (A -| B) {SomeName};
```

or use a coordinate:

```
\coordinate (someName) at (A -| B);
```

An additional option is to use the `let` path operation from the `calc` library, described on page 161 of the 3.0.0 manual:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines, step=0.5cm] (-2.5,0) grid (0,2.5);
    \node (A) at (-0.5,0.5) {A};
    \node (B) at (-2,2) {B};
    \path let \p1 = (A), \p2 = (B) in node (C) at (\x1,\y2) {C} node (D) at (\x2,\y1) {D};
    \draw (C.center) -- (D.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can also do other calculations on the points, using the other facilities of the `calc` library; I suggest you check out that chapter in the manual! :-)

Comment: How would you combine that with`$ ... $` expressions as done [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/combining-and-5-in-tikz) : `\path ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) |- node[red] {X} ($(C)!0.5!(D)$);` ?

Comment: @hillbilly Can you clarify your question? Combine what with what?

Comment: Definitions of nodes with `$ ... $`. So combining with all kinds of calc expressions. Something like `\node (someName) at (($A - (0,1)$) -| B) {};` or (since this is equal to `$(A -| B) - (0,1)$` - which works) expresions using `(A)!0.5!(B)` like in that other question linked above.

Comment: @hillbilly Do you mean something like `\path ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) -| node[red] (X) {X} (C);`?