# Nested coordinate calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates

I have the following coordinate calculation

```
\coordinate (a0) at ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$);
\coordinate (a1) at ($(c3 -| a0) + (1,3)$);
\draw (a1) rectangle (b1);
```

I wanted to eliminate the first coordinate and use this code instead

```
\coordinate (a1) at ($(c3 -| ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)) + (1,3)$);
\draw (a1) rectangle (b1);
```

But it doesn't work, even when I put curly braces around the coordinate `($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/combining-and-5-in-tikz

Comment: That's in fact a duplicate in my opinion. Would you agree @Reza?

Comment: It's very similar but there is an addidtion involved and only one coordinate lays between two points

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
\coordinate (a1) at ($(c3 -| ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)) + (1,3)$);
```

gives you this error message:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named `($(c1' is known.
```

which is a clue what's happening. Notice two things:

The name PGF/TikZ is looking up starts with an `(` and end right before the first `)`.

In fact, let's remove one layer and try

```
\coordinate (a1) at (c3 -| ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$));
```

This gives the same error message.

Two things are wrong here, the first is simple. When you specify a coordinate at the intersection of [`perpendicular`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular) lines through two other points, you do *not* specify them enclosed in `(` and `)`. You didn't do it with `c3`, either!
Let's remove one set of parentheses:

```
 \coordinate (a1) at (c3 -| $(c1)!0.5!(c2)$);
```

Still won't work:

```
! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.

l.9 \coordinate (a1) at (c3 -| $(c1)
                                    !0.5!(c2)$);
```

The message itself isn't very helpful but the next line shows us where TikZ tripped up.

When TikZ encounters a `(` it will – with the exception of `($`, actually – grab everything until the next `)` and assumes that to be the coordinate. Here it will have `c3 -| $(c1` as the coordinate and everything breaks down. As with [mathematical function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662447/16595), the `)` needs to be hidden from the greedy parser:

```
\coordinate (a1) at (c3 -| {$(c1)!0.5!(c2)$});
```

And that's actually all, now that can be put as one coordinate of your coordinate sum:

```
\coordinate (a1) at ($(c3 -| {$(c1)!0.5!(c2)$}) + (1,3)$);
```

When the parser finds `($` it will hand of the coordinate parsing to the `calc` library which will find another `(` and hands the parsing of the number back to TikZ (which will grab greedily, finds `c3` and `$(c1)!0.5!(c2)$` where the latter will be handed back to `calc` because of the `$`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (b1) at (rnd, rnd)
 coordinate (c1) at (rnd, rnd)
 coordinate (c2) at (rnd, rnd)
 coordinate (c3) at (rnd, rnd);
\coordinate (a1) at ($(c3 -| {$(c1)!0.5!(c2)$}) + (1,3)$);
% alternatives:
% \coordinate (a1) at ([shift={(1,3)}] c3 -| {$(c1)!0.5!(c2)$});
% \coordinate (a1) at ([shift={(1,3)}] perpendicular cs:
%   horizontal line through = {(c3)},
%   vertical line through   = {($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)});
\draw (a1) rectangle (b1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice detective work!