# What is the right way to calculate square root in coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying to create a file demonstrating the pythagorean theorem.

In this example the hypotenuse has length 4 while the base length 3. So the height should be square root of 7.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (3,0) {B};
\node (C) at (0,\pgrmathparse{sqrt(7)}\pgfmathresult) {C};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I cannot place the node for height. Swapping line 9 with `\node (C) at (0,sqrt(7)) {C};` does not fix the issue. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just write `(0, sqrt 7)` or `(0, {sqrt(7)})` protecting the `)` from the parser.

Comment: Please post an example that can be compiled without errors.

Comment: Related: [Q659050](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/659050)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
\node (C) at (0,\pgfmathparse{sqrt(7)}\pgfmathresult) {C};
```

will not work because TikZ expects fully expandable content in coordinate specifications (and `\pgfmathparse` is not).

As TikZ already throws everything in PGFmath you can just use `sqrt(7)` directly but you need to protect the `)` from the parser because said parser is not smart and will grab everything until the next `)` ­– even if the parentheses are unbalanced then.

So, you need

```
\node (C) at (0, {sqrt(7)}) {C};
```

Though, in this simple case, you can also write just

```
\node (C) at (0, sqrt 7) {C};
```

---

I've added a second TikZ picture which I believe looks more like something I believe you want.

---

Because PGFmath if forgiving, you could even do

```
at (0, sqrt(7)
```

but this isn't Code Golf.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (3,0) {B};
\node (C) at (0, sqrt 7) {C};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=left: $A$] (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate[label=right:$B$] (B) at (3, 0);
\coordinate[label=left: $C$] (C) at (0, sqrt 7);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]