# Confusion over missing bracket in TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to recreate a multi meter and have created the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2}   
\draw[thick,fill=black] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\draw[thick] ($(0,0)+(45:\R cm)$) arc (45:135:\R);
\foreach \x/\y  [count=\xi]  in {45/3,50/2.5,60/2,72/1.5,90/1,115.5/0.5,135/0}
{
    \draw[thick] ($(0,0)+(\x:\R cm)$) -- ($(0,0)+(\x:\R+0.2+0.28*Mod(\xi-1,2)$);
    \node[rotate=\x-90] at ($(0,0)+(\x:\R+0.4+0.3*Mod(\xi-1,2)$) {\y};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As far as I understand, this must be the correct code, with an extra bracket after Mod.

```
\node[rotate=\x-90] at ($(0,0)+(\x:\R+0.4+0.3*Mod(\xi-1,2))$) {\y};
```

But this gives the following error:
! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.

Comment: Welcome. What's `\R`? You've got to [hide the `)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662447/16595) of the `Mod` function from the TikZ parser: `($(0,0)+(\x:{\R+0.2+0.28*Mod(\xi-1,2)})$)`. (Of course, the `(0,0)+` is pointless here but that's another topic. You're also mixing coordinates from the canvas (with units) and from the *xyz* (without units) coordinate systems which I advise against unless it is necessary.)

Comment: I've just noticed that `(\x:{\R+0.2+0.28*Mod(\xi-1,2)` actually works because of a quirk in PGFMath so I don't know what your issue is besides not having `\R` not defined. Once I define `\R`, your code works for me. Maybe you have an older installation of your TeX distribution or of PGF/TikZ.

Comment: I had problems, to get '(\x:\R+0.4+0.3*Mod(\xi-1,2))' running, but when I accidentally deleted the last bracket, the code was running. I can not understand this and want to know, if this is a bug or a misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: See the linked answer. When TikZ finds a coordinate it grabs everything until the next `)` and then tries to parse this as a coordinate. If you use `*Mod(\xi-1,2))` it will find the first `)` and the radius of the polar coordinate will be `\R+0.2+0.28*Mod(\xi-1,2`. PGFMath is forgiving and doesn't care about the missing `)` but then TikZ finds the second `)` and that doesn't the path syntax and it raises an error. If you use only one `)`, PGFMath gets the same formula, still forgiving but TikZ can go on. (That's the equivalent to the “code golf” example `(0, sqrt(7)` in the link.)

Comment: The proper way (and if the function doesn't occur at the end the only way) is to put the whole radius inside `{}` to *protect* the occuring `)` from the TikZ parser which isn't as smart as when PGFMath parses a formula (and matches the `()` correctly, of course).

Comment: Thank you Qrrbrbirlbel for this explanation. Especially the hint with the {} brackets. Now I can write my code in a way, that I know it will work as intended.